# How to round up the result of integer division?

Tags: java, c#, c++, math

I'm thinking in particular of how to display pagination controls, when using a language such as C# or Java.

If I have *x* items which I want to display in chunks of *y* per page, how many pages will be needed?

Comment: Am I missing something? y/x + 1 works great (provided you know the / operator always rounds down).

Comment: @rikkit - if y and x are equal, y/x + 1 is one too high.

Comment: For anyone just now finding this, [this answer to a dupe question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4846569/4163002) avoids unnecessary conversion to double *and* avoids overflow concerns in addition to providing a clear explanation.

Comment: @IanNelson more generally if `x` is divisible by `y`, `y/x + 1` would be one too high.

Comment: @ZX9 No, it does not avoid overflow concerns. It's exactly the same solution as Ian Nelson posted here.

Answer (score 585, accepted):

Found an elegant solution:

```
int pageCount = (records + recordsPerPage - 1) / recordsPerPage;
```

Source: [Number Conversion, Roland Backhouse, 2001](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~rcb/G51MPC/slides/NumberLogic.pdf)

Comment: -1 because of the overflow bug pointed out by [Brandon DuRette](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944/how-to-round-up-the-result-of-integer-division/96921#96921)

Comment: Mr Obvious says: Remember to make sure that recordsPerPage is not zero

Comment: Good job, I can't believe C# doesn't have integer ceiling.

Comment: Yup, here I am in mid-2017 stumbling across this great answer after trying several much more complex approaches.

Comment: For languages with a proper Euclidian-division operator such as Python, an even simpler approach would be `pageCount = -((-records) // recordsPerPage)`.

Comment: +1 because this also works with unsigned numbers (relevant in other languages): The "simplification" `(records - 1) / recordsPerPage + 1` underflows when records == 0.

Comment: It does have Ceiling.  It's under Math, not Integer.

Comment: Thanks, the solution is elegant without external libraries.

@finnw to avoid the overflow bug, just split in two divisions 
`int pageCount = records / recordsPerPage + (recordsPerPage - 1) / recordsPerPage;`

Comment: I spent awhile on ChatGPT and came up with `int result = x / y + ((x % y + y - 1) / y);`, but @Ian Nelson's answer is simpler to read and more computationally efficient (and GPT agrees).

Answer (score 251):

Converting to floating point and back seems like a huge waste of time at the CPU level.

Ian Nelson's solution:

```
int pageCount = (records + recordsPerPage - 1) / recordsPerPage;
```

Can be simplified to:

```
int pageCount = ((records - 1) / recordsPerPage) + 1;
```

AFAICS, this doesn't have the overflow bug that Brandon DuRette pointed out, and because it only uses it once, you don't need to store the recordsPerPage specially if it comes from  an expensive function to fetch the value from a config file or something.

I.e. this might be inefficient, if config.fetch_value used a database lookup or something:

```
int pageCount = (records + config.fetch_value('records per page') - 1) / config.fetch_value('records per page');
```

This creates a variable you don't really need, which probably has (minor) memory implications and is just too much typing:

```
int recordsPerPage = config.fetch_value('records per page')
int pageCount = (records + recordsPerPage - 1) / recordsPerPage;
```

This is all one line, and only fetches the data once:

```
int pageCount = (records - 1) / config.fetch_value('records per page') + 1;
```

Comment: +1, the issue of zero records still returning 1 pageCount is actually handy, since I would still want 1 page, showing the placeholder/fake row of "no records match your criteria", helps avoid any "0 page count" issues in whatever pagination control you use.

Comment: Be aware that the two solutions do not return the same pageCount for zero records. This simplified version will return 1 pageCount for zero records, whereas the Roland Backhouse version returns 0 pageCount. Fine if that's what you desire, but the two equations are not equivalent when performed by C#/Java stylee integer division.

Comment: tiny edit for clarity for people scanning it and missing bodmas when changing to the simpification from the Nelson solution (like I did the first time !), the simplification with brackets is...

int pageCount = ((records - 1) / recordsPerPage) + 1;

Comment: You should add parenthesis to the simplified version so that it doesn't rely on a specific order of operations. i.e., ((records - 1) / recordsPerPage) + 1.

Comment: Also, it's simpler to translate it to other division problems; Good to know there's a simple way to do ceiling division with integers.

Comment: @Ian, this answer doesn't ALWAYS return 1.  It can return 0 if your recordsPerPage is "1" and there are 0 records: `-1 / 1 + 1 = 0`.  While that's not a super common occurrence, it's important to keep in mind if you're allowing users to adjust page size.  So either don't allow users to have a page size of 1, do a check on page size, or both (probably preferable to avoid unexpected behavior).

Comment: This is no solution for the overflow, though. With Ian's solution you get twice the usable range if you use unsigned integers, and `records + recordsPerPage` has an upper bound of 2^32 or 2^64. With this solution you can only use a signed integer for `records`, otherwise it will overflow at `0 - 1`, so `records` is upper bound by 2^31 or 2^63.

Comment: FWIW, I was doing something similar, calculating the max page number, and if the page numbers are 0-based, it becomes a nice, clean... maxPage = (records - 1) / recordsPerPage.  Only thing is it has the same issue when records==0... if recordsPerPage is 1, the result is -1 (what I'd want) but if recordsPerPage>1, you get 0.

Answer (score 101):

For C# the solution is to cast the values to a double (as Math.Ceiling takes a double):

```
int nPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)nItems / (double)nItemsPerPage);
```

In java you should do the same with Math.ceil().

Comment: why is this answer so far down when the op asks for C# explicitly!

Comment: You also need to cast the output to `int` because `Math.Ceiling` returns a `double` or `decimal`, depending on the input types.

Comment: because it is extremely inefficient

Comment: It may be inefficient but it's extremely easy to understand. Given calculating a page count is usually done once per request any performance loss wouldn't be measurable.

Comment: Its barely more readable than this "(dividend + (divisor - 1)) / divisor;" also its slow and requires the math library.

Comment: @rolls I think by readable he ment that intention is much clearer.

Comment: The intention is clear but the casts make it ugly.

Comment: Don't write computationally inefficient code that is "clearer" when you could just write a good comment explaining what/why an efficient but esoteric piece of code is doing, and/or wrap it as a property or method to keep it clean and clear and consistent.

Answer (score 87):

This should give you what you want.  You will definitely want x items divided by y items per page, the problem is when uneven numbers come up, so if there is a partial page we also want to add one page.

```
int x = number_of_items;
int y = items_per_page;

// with out library
int pages = x/y + (x % y > 0 ? 1 : 0)

// with library
int pages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)x / (double)y);
```

Comment: x/y + !!(x % y) avoids the branch for C-like languages.  Odds are good, however, your compiler is doing that anyway.

Comment: +1 for not overflowing like the answers above... though converting ints to doubles just for Math.ceiling and then back again is a bad idea in performance sensitive code.

Comment: @RhysUlerich that doesn't work in c# (can't directly convert an int to a bool). rjmunro's solution is the only way to avoid branching I think.

Comment: @smead No type cast/conversion is performed, just an inline function call. It does work rather elegantly in C# because it's an inline IF function returning an integer 1 or 0, where two operands are tested in a function call that (implicitly) returns int, which the compiler will certainly assume based on the type receiving the value assignment and the type compatibility of the literals returned by the IIF.

Answer (score 19):

The integer math solution that Ian provided is nice, but suffers from an integer overflow bug. Assuming the variables are all `int`, the solution could be rewritten to use `long` math and avoid the bug:

`int pageCount = (-1L + records + recordsPerPage) / recordsPerPage;`

If `records` is a `long`, the bug remains. The modulus solution does not have the bug.

Comment: I don't think you are realistically going to hit this bug in the scenario presented. 2^31 records is quite a lot to be having to page through.

Comment: @rjmunro, [real-world example here](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=616)

Comment: @finnw: AFAICS, there isn't a real-world example on that page, just a report of someone else finding the bug in a theoretical scenario.

Comment: @rjmunro, I was referring to this: *"I came across this oddity while I was working on an SWT-based table viewer that supports pagination. Internally, the table viewer uses Lists.partition() to split its input elements into pages of a fixed size."*

Comment: Yes, I was being pedantic in pointing out the bug. Many bugs can exist in perpetuity without ever causing any problems. A bug of the same form existed in the JDK's implementation of binarySearch for some nine years, before someone reported it (http://googleresearch.blogspot.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html). I guess the question is, regardless of how unlikely you are to encounter this bug, why not fix it up front?

Comment: Also, it should be noted that it's not just the number of elements that are paged that matter, it's also the page size. So, if you're building a library and someone chooses to not page by passing 2^31-1 (Integer.MAX_VALUE) as the page size, then the bug is triggered.

Answer (score 12):

**HOW TO ROUND UP THE RESULT OF INTEGER DIVISION IN C#**

I was interested to know what the best way is to do this in C# since I need to do this in a loop up to nearly 100k times. Solutions posted by others using *Math* are ranked high in the answers, but in testing I found them slow. Jarod Elliott proposed a better tactic in checking if mod produces anything.

```
int result = (int1 / int2);
if (int1 % int2 != 0) { result++; }
```

I ran this in a loop 1 million times and it took 8ms. Here is the code using *Math*:

```
int result = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)int1 / (double)int2);
```

Which ran at 14ms in my testing, considerably longer.

Note: the first method may fail if you're working with negative numbers.

Comment: Yeah, floating point division is pretty "terrible". :) This truth goes way back since the dawn of the first floating point CPU's/FPU's, really. In fact, many game developers and others demanding high performance go through hoops to be able to use integer math.

Comment: I'm going to make an assumption that it takes longer because they're bigger data types, more digits to manage.

Comment: What happens if int1 is -1 and int2 is 2? Do you really want to round -0.5 to 1.0 ?

Comment: @EricLippert good point. If you're working with negative numbers the first method may fail. I'll add a note about it.

Answer (score 8):

A variant of [Nick Berardi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944/how-to-round-up-the-result-of-integer-division/17954#17954) that avoids a branch:

```
int q = records / recordsPerPage, r = records % recordsPerPage;
int pageCount = q - (-r >> (Integer.SIZE - 1));
```

Note: `(-r >> (Integer.SIZE - 1))` consists of the sign bit of `r`, repeated 32 times (thanks to sign extension of the `>>` operator.)  This evaluates to 0 if `r` is zero or negative, -1 if `r` is positive.  So subtracting it from `q` has the effect of adding 1 if `records % recordsPerPage > 0`.

Answer (score 8):

In need of an extension method:

```
    public static int DivideUp(this int dividend, int divisor)
    {
        return (dividend + (divisor - 1)) / divisor;
    }
```

No checks here (overflow, `DivideByZero`, etc), feel free to add if you like. By the way, for those worried about method invocation overhead, simple functions like this might be inlined by the compiler anyways, so I don't think that's where to be concerned. Cheers.

P.S. you might find it useful to be aware of this as well (it gets the remainder):

```
    int remainder; 
    int result = Math.DivRem(dividend, divisor, out remainder);
```

Comment: This is incorrect. For example: `DivideUp(4, -2)` returns 0 (should be -2). **It is only correct for non-negative integers** which is not clear from the answer or from the function's interface.

Comment: Thash, why don't you do something useful like add the little extra check then if the number is negative, instead of voting my answer down, and incorrectly making the blanket statement: "This is incorrect," when in fact it's just an edge case. I already made it clear you should do other checks first: "No checks here (overflow, DivideByZero, etc), **feel free to add if you like**."

Comment: The question mentioned "I'm thinking in particular of how to display **pagination controls**" so negative numbers would have been out of bounds anyways. Again, just do something useful and suggest an added check if you want, it's a team effort man.

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude and I'm sorry if you take it that way. The question was "How to round up the result of integer division". The author mentioned pagination but other people may have different needs. I think it would be better if your function somehow reflected that it does not work for negative integers since it is not clear from the interface (for example a differen name or argument types). To work with negative integers,you can for example take an absolute value of the dividend and divisor and multiply the result by its sign.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is to use the mod() function (or '%'). If there is a non-zero remainder then increment the integer result of the division.

Answer (score 4):

For records == 0, rjmunro's solution gives 1.  The correct solution is 0.  That said, if you know that records > 0 (and I'm sure we've all assumed recordsPerPage > 0), then rjmunro solution gives correct results and does not have any of the overflow issues.

```
int pageCount = 0;
if (records > 0)
{
    pageCount = (((records - 1) / recordsPerPage) + 1);
}
// no else required
```

**All** the integer math solutions are going to be more efficient than *any* of the floating point solutions.

Comment: This method is unlikely to be a performance bottleneck.  And if it is, you should also consider the cost of the branch.

Answer (score 2):

I do the following, handles any overflows:

```
var totalPages = totalResults.IsDivisble(recordsperpage) ? totalResults/(recordsperpage) : totalResults/(recordsperpage) + 1;
```

And use this extension for if there's 0 results:

```
public static bool IsDivisble(this int x, int n)
{
           return (x%n) == 0;
}
```

Also, for the current page number (wasn't asked but could be useful):

```
var currentPage = (int) Math.Ceiling(recordsperpage/(double) recordsperpage) + 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use

```
(int)Math.Ceiling(((decimal)model.RecordCount )/ ((decimal)4));
```

Comment: What if the number of records per page is something other than 4?

Comment: Thank you.
Your response is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to remove branching in testing for zero:

```
int pageCount = (records + recordsPerPage - 1) / recordsPerPage * (records != 0);
```

Not sure if this will work in C#, should do in C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

I made this for me, thanks to [Jarod Elliott](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17953/7210166) & [SendETHToThisAddress](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63012251/7210166) replies.

```
public static int RoundedUpDivisionBy(this int @this, int divider)
{        
    var result = @this / divider;
    if (@this % divider is 0) return result;
    return result + Math.Sign(@this * divider);
}
```

Then I realized it is overkill for the CPU compared to the top answer.
However, I think it's readable and works with negative numbers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 18, `Math.ceilDiv` is available for this purpose, see https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#ceilDiv(int,int)

Answer (score -1):

A generic method, whose result you can iterate over may be of interest:

```
public static Object[][] chunk(Object[] src, int chunkSize) {

    int overflow = src.length%chunkSize;
    int numChunks = (src.length/chunkSize) + (overflow>0?1:0);
    Object[][] dest = new Object[numChunks][];      
    for (int i=0; i<numChunks; i++) {
        dest[i] = new Object[ (i<numChunks-1 || overflow==0) ? chunkSize : overflow ];
        System.arraycopy(src, i*chunkSize, dest[i], 0, dest[i].length); 
    }
    return dest;
}
```

Comment: [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) has a similar method ([`Lists.partition(List, int)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition%28java.util.List,%20int%29)) and ironically the `size()` method of the resulting `List` (as of `r09`) suffers from the overflow bug mentioned in [Brandon DuRette's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944/how-to-round-up-the-result-of-integer-division/96921#96921).

Answer (score -2):

The following should do rounding better than the above solutions, but at the expense of performance (due to floating point calculation of 0.5*rctDenominator):

```
uint64_t integerDivide( const uint64_t& rctNumerator, const uint64_t& rctDenominator )
{
  // Ensure .5 upwards is rounded up (otherwise integer division just truncates - ie gives no remainder)
  return (rctDenominator == 0) ? 0 : (rctNumerator + (int)(0.5*rctDenominator)) / rctDenominator;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I had a similar need where I needed to convert Minutes to hours & minutes. What I used was:

```
int hrs = 0; int mins = 0;

float tm = totalmins;

if ( tm > 60 ) ( hrs = (int) (tm / 60);

mins = (int) (tm - (hrs * 60));

System.out.println("Total time in Hours & Minutes = " + hrs + ":" + mins);
```

Answer (score -5):

You'll want to do floating point division, and then use the ceiling function, to round up the value to the next integer.