# Correct way to convert 8 bools into 1 byte

Tags: c#, optimization, boolean, byte

Simple question: considering that a bool (true, false) is the same as a bit (1, 0), what is the correct way to convert eight bools into a byte in C#?

Examples:

true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true == 11111111 == 255

true, false, false, false, false, false, false, false == 10000000 == 128

false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false == 00000000 == 0

The above is the first part. I want to create an extension method, like that:

```
    public static byte[] ToByteArray(this bool[] bitArray)
    {
          // stuff here
          return byteArray;    
    }
```

The result must be a byteArray that contains eight times less elements than the bool array.

Comment: You're asking how to covert 8 bools into a byte, but your example method is returning a byte array.

Comment: Yep, like I said, the byteArray is the second part, first I need to convert 8 bools to 1 byte

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You probabbly searching for [BitArray Constructor (Boolean[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twk7f5c5.aspx)

For rapresenting bits you have special structure `BitArray` in `C#`.
So your code would look like this:

```
var booleans = new bool[]{true, false, false, false};
var bitArray = new BitArray(booleans);
```

Comment: Is a good solution, but beware of the bug when specified a length and using `SetAll(true)` because that would result in -1(which is all bits for an int), instead of the given length.

Comment: So, how can I return a byte[] from that?

Comment: @Guilherme: `CopyTo()`.

Comment: @Guilherme http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560123/convert-from-bitarray-to-byte

Answer (score 1):

Robust solution (just in case).

Split them into groups of 8 somehow (depending on the order and how you want to *adjust* them - to `LSB` or `RSB`), then form an array by calling this method in the cycle:

```
byte GetByte(bool[] bits)
{
    byte result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < bits.Length; i++)
        if(byte[i])
            result |= 1 << i;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @LS_dev, yeah thanks. I mentioned, what `bytes` for method should be *prepared* first ^^, but you can add bound check and throw `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` or whatever if you want to, it was just an example of how easy to convert anything into bits.