# how to save a huge amount of integers in a data file without consuming too much disk space in c?

Tags: c

I'm running a simulation with 20000 sweeps, and for every sweep, I need to save a very large array of integers with the values 1, and -1 to a data file.
The number of integers printed can reach 1e11.

my problem is that the size of the data file becomes huge (up to 50GB)

I'm currently using `fprintf` with `int` datatype.

does anyone know a way to save these values without taking that much disk space?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the integer can only take on two values, then you can fit each entry into a single bit using techniques such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18722460/correct-way-to-convert-8-bools-into-1-byte) and binary (rather than text) file handling. With this technique, 1e11 bits will require [12.5 GB](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%281e11%29+bits+to+gigabytes) which is the best you can do without finding specific patterns. Please take a look at these (or other techniques you're considering) and [edit] your question with additional detail if you end up needing help with them.

Comment: Another option that may be viable with that data set is to apply simple [run length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding).

Comment: Note that your constraint is *disk space*, not *memory*.

Comment: Similar to RLE is if there are relatively few of one value, just save a list of their indexes after the first two entries which says how many, and which value.

Comment: @WeatherVane RLE doesn't work in my case because I need the indices of the values and keeping a list won't help either because, in the end, I will have to print them to a data folder that will be used in matlab, which will lead me to print the same amount of data, but thanks for the tip :)

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for the heads up, I just changed it

Comment: @nanofarad would this work in C?
I think the link you attached answers a different question, could you please check if its the right link?

Comment: @SaraAwwad dividing data into chunks (like 1 KB ... 1 MB ... 1 GB depending on your constraints)  you can decompress into memory (basically a cache)  on demand would allow using RLE encoding on the chunks while also being able to use indexing efficiently.

Comment: @SaraAwwad Sorry, that is indeed the wrong language (I was inattentive while searching). [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8461163/1424875) is for C++, but you should be able to use the first two code samples with some small modifications (and `#include <stdbool.h>` since they don't make use of C++-specific constructs.

Comment: "*RLE doesn't work in my case because I need the indices of the values*". It's not clear what you mean by that. RLE does not prevent you from calculating the index of any of the data values.

Comment: One bit per number + compression algorithm? zstd or gzip or whatever

Comment: @kaylum I'm sorry I meant sth else
RLE requires the data to be repetitive to work, (i.e it works if I have sth like this: [11111-1-1-1-111111]), but it makes the dataset bigger if I have too many singular data points (i.e sth like this [1-11-1-11-111]) which is why using it will only make things worse
It's also explained in the wiki page shared with me above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If your numbers are only `-1` and `1` then it can be represented in one bit. If number `0` also exists you will need an additional one bit to represent 3 values (2 bits can actually hold 4 distinct values).
2. 1e11 bits can be represented in 12.5e9 bytes. If two bits are required then 25.0e9 bytes will be needed. It is not a problem for most modern computers. You may even have enough RAM to keep it in RAM or map it.

for single bit:

```
int getVal1bit(const void *buff, size_t index)
{
    const unsigned char *ucbuff = buff;

    ucbuff += index / CHAR_BIT;

    return *ucbuff & (1 << (index % 8)) ? 1 : -1;
}

void putVal1bit(void *buff, size_t index, int val)
{
    unsigned char *ucbuff = buff;

    ucbuff += index / CHAR_BIT;

    if(val < 0) *ucbuff |= (1 << (index % 8));
    else *ucbuff &= ~(1 << (index % 8));
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer but I don't fully understand the code, why index%8 ?

Comment: @SaraAwwad to get the particular bit in the byte.