# Change from bitarray to enum

Tags: c#, enums, flags

I currently have some crude google code.. that works but I want to swap to an enum.

Currently I need a byte to represent some bit flags that are set,

I currently have this:

```
 BitArray bitArray =new BitArray(new bool[] { true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false });
```

used in line..

```
new byte[] {ConvertToByte(bitArray)})
```

with ConvertToByte from this site...

```
    private static byte ConvertToByte(BitArray bits) // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560123/convert-from-bitarray-to-byte
    {
        if (bits.Count != 8)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("incorrect number of bits");
        }
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1];
        bits.CopyTo(bytes, 0);
        return bytes[0];
    }
```

However I wanted to use an enum as I touched on, so I created it as so:

```
[Flags]
public enum EventMessageTypes
{
    None = 0,
    aaa = 1, 
    bbb = 2, 
    ccc = 4, 
    ddd = 8, 
    eee = 16,
    fff = 32,   
    All = aaa | bbb | ccc | ddd | eee | fff // All Events
}
```

and then

```
        // Do bitwise OR to combine the values we want
        EventMessageTypes eventMessages = EventMessageTypes.aaa | EventMessageTypes.bbb | EventMessageTypes.ccc;
```

But how do I then get eventMessages to a byte (0x07) I think! so I can append that to my byte array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just simply cast it to byte!.
example:

```
byte eventMessages =(byte)( EventMessageTypes.aaa | EventMessageTypes.bbb | EventMessageTypes.ccc);
```

Comment: Hmm... Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS0019 Operator '|' cannot be applied to operands of type 'byte' and 'EventMessageTypes'

Comment: @David Wallis  pay attention to parenthesis please and try again. close all (|) operands to parenthesis and cast all to byte as one statement. for example this statement might be an error:    `(byte)enum.value1|enum.value2;`  because just value1 casted to byte. insert your code if still getting error.

Comment: @David Wallis  I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

[Here's one way](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QrWgf0):

```
var bitArray = new BitArray(
    new [] { true, true, false, false, false, false, false, false });
var eventMessages = (EventMessageTypes)bitArray
    .Cast<Boolean>()
    .Reverse()
    .Aggregate(0, (agg, b) => (agg << 1) + (b ? 1 : 0));
```

[Download for LinqPad](http://share.linqpad.net/4roaoj.linq)

Answer (score 2):

You have a way of getting a `byte`, so now just cast:

```
byte b = ConvertToByte(bitArray);
EventMessageTypes a = (EventMessageTypes) b;
```

Also, a tip, restrict the enum range to `byte` to prevent someone later adding out of range values to the enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum EventMessageTypes : byte
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: duh.. why didn't I think of that.. will try the restricting the range too.. Will have to wait until later and will post results. :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem right, then in essence you can cast to enum like this `EventMessageTypes result = (EventMessageTypes)ConvertToByte(bitArray);`

```
BitArray bitArray = new BitArray(new bool[] 
    { true, true, false, false, 
      false, false, false, false });
EventMessageTypes b = (EventMessageTypes)ConvertToByte(bitArray);
```

you could for readability and future code reuse make a extension class

```
static class Extension
{
    public static byte ToByte(this BitArray bits)
    {
        if (bits.Count != 8)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("incorrect number of bits");
        }
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1];
        bits.CopyTo(bytes, 0);
        return bytes[0];
    }

    static class EnumConverter<TEnum> where TEnum : struct, IConvertible
    {
        public static readonly Func<long, TEnum> Convert = GenerateConverter();

        static Func<long, TEnum> GenerateConverter()
        {
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(long));
            var dynamicMethod = Expression.Lambda<Func<long, TEnum>>(
                Expression.Convert(parameter, typeof(TEnum)),
                parameter);
            return dynamicMethod.Compile();
        }
    }
    public static T ToEnum<T>(this byte b) where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enumerated type");
        }
        return EnumConverter<T>.Convert(b);
    }
}
```

Then you can write the convert like this. `bitArray.ToByte()` or even better like this `EventMessageTypes b = bitArray.ToByte().ToEnum<EventMessageTypes>();`

Comment: I dont want to use the bit array, - that's what I want to swap for the enum and then the values with the bitwise or.

Comment: well then, how do you get/generate the data? as bools/bits or bytes

Comment: you can convert int to enum by `(enum)int/byte` and the other way around  `(int/byte)enum`