# How do I convert a boolean list to int?

Tags: c#, list, int, boolean

How do I convert a boolean list to an integer equal to the Booleans interpreted as a byte?

i.e.

```
public List<Boolean> MyList = new List<Boolean>();
MyList.Add(true);
MyList.Add(true);
MyList.Add(false);
MyList.Add(false);
MyList.Add(false);
MyList.Add(false);
MyList.Add(false);
MyList.Add(false);
```

This would return a 3.

Comment: Why would that return 4?

Comment: How this would returns 4? Are you trying to make some binary calculation? Even then how this return 4?

Comment: For everybody asking about how it's 4. I think he wants false to be -1 and true to be +1. It would be -2 + 6 = 4. The question definitely needs some clarification.

Comment: Sorry a 3...not a 4. Binary to int. I apologize for the confusion!

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Good call. Turns out it was supposed to be binary afterall anyway.

Comment: I mean I can do a for loop and just do the math...I was just wondering if there was an elegant solution. Again sorry for the confusion!

Comment: Look at the [`BitArray` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx)

Comment: @Ken: For loop and do the math is the way. Note that in the future you should show how calling `Add` translates into binary so that people understand.

Answer (score 4):

You can't, at least not directly.

You *can* however use the `BitArray` class ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray(v=vs.110).aspx)) to transform your `bool` collection to bits, and then get a number from that:

```
BitArray bitField = new BitArray(MyList.ToArray()); //BitArray takes a bool[]
byte[] bytes = new byte[1];
bitField.CopyTo(bytes, 0);
return bytes[0];
```

BitArray to value conversion from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/560131/1783619

Note that this technique works for numbers larger than 8-bit as well, but you would need to use `BitConverter` ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx)) to get the values back from the byte array (instead of just returning the first one)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a one line solution, you could use the aggregate function to calculate the equivalent int value.

```
var boolList = new List<bool> { true, false, false, false, false, true, false, false };

int integerVal = boolList.Aggregate(0, (sum,val) => (sum * 2) + (val ? 1 : 0));
```

Here, integerVal is 132, which is equivalent to the binary value 10000100.

Answer (score 0):

check this in console app.
First of all, after entering the desired values into the list, you must reverse your list, then you create a string value, and then using a loop, you convert the values into 0 and 1, and finally, you convert from binary to hex.

```
using System.Data.SqlTypes;

List<bool> boolList = new();

boolList.Add(true);
boolList.Add(true);
boolList.Add(false);
boolList.Add(false);
boolList.Add(false);
boolList.Add(false);
boolList.Add(false);
boolList.Add(false);

boolList.Reverse();

string s = string.Empty;

boolList.ForEach(item =>
{
    s += item ? "1" : "0";
});


Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(s, 2).ToString("X"));
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score -1):

This isn't really an actual algorithm on how we can convert the list of bool into an int, but we can accomplish this task by converting a list of bools to a string representing a binary digit (e.g. 1s and 0s), and then convert the string back to int:

```cs
public static int BoolListToInt32(List<bool> list)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new();
        
    list.ForEach(b => sb.Append(b ? '1' : '0'));
    return Convert.ToInt32(sb.ToString(), 2);
}
```

The following example returns 3 expectedly:

```cs
List<bool> list = new() { false, false, false, false, false, false, true, true };
        
Console.WriteLine(BoolListToInt32(list));
```

And it's very fast as well, so performance is not a thing to worry about (just telling).

[Experiment with the example on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3xGsf2)