# How to insert/store a BitArray into Snowflake database?

Tags: c#, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am writing an application that is meant to compare data in two files.  The files have a defined number of columns, and to track the differences between the files, I intended to use a [`BitArray`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray?view=net-7.0) (specifically, a [`BitArray(bool[])`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.bitarray.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-collections-bitarray-ctor(system-boolean()))), where a value of `true` indicates that the column matched between the two files, and `false` indicates they did not match.

Thus a `BitArray` like so would indicate that the first column across the files does not match, and the second column did:

```cs
BitArray bitArray = new BitArray(new bool[2] { false, true });
```

The column on the table I want to insert this `BitArray` into is of type `BINARY(200)` (and I do have control over changing this if needed). I've been reading over the [binary documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/binary-input-output) from Snowflake, and I am unsure if this is correct data type for this.  At the very least, my attempts to insert the data into the table have failed.  I was *hoping* to be able to insert the data and it appear as something like `01` (`false` and `true` in the order of the `BitArray`).

My C# code is (simplified):

```
BitArray bitArray = new BitArray(new bool[2] { false, true });
string testSql = @"INSERT INTO MY_TABLE VALUES (TO_BINARY(:bitArrayParam))";

DbCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = testSql;

DbParameter bitArrayParam= command.CreateParameter();
bitArrayParam.DbType = DbType.Binary;
bitArrayParam.Value = bitArray;
bitArrayParam.ParameterName = "bitArrayParam";
command.Parameters.Add(bitArrayParam);

await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
```

This results in an error:

> Failed to convert data System.Collections.BitArray from type System.Collections.BitArray to type Binary.

I realize the type is part of the issue, but I assume simply trying to insert the `BitArray` as a whole won't work.  Is there a different format I need to use that can achieve the desired `01` results getting inserted?

Comment: Seems C# has trouble serializing a BitArray - try the solution here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/58279913/132438

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I did consider using a string of zeroes and ones, but didn't want to do that if I could avoid it.  I'll have to see if that's a viable way forward. Won't be able to try until next week.  Why this as a solution? Is it because of how the .NET connector essentially uses a web Api?

Comment: Consider storing a Snowflake Array of True/False values. Or you could serialize as Ints https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5283180/how-can-i-convert-bitarray-to-single-int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up using was taking the `BitArray` and copying it to a `byte[]` and then iterate over (backwards) the `byte[]` to create the hexadecimal string to store into the binary column in Snowflake.

```cs
private string ConvertArrayToHex(BitArray bitArr)
{
    byte[] byteArr = new byte[(int)Math.Ceiling(bitArr.Length / 8.0)];
    bitArr.CopyTo(byteArr, 0);

    StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(byteArr.Length * 2);

    for (int i = byteArr.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--) //Decrement (i.e. work backwards)
    {
        hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", byteArr[i]);
    } 

    return hex.ToString();
}
```

Thus, a `BitArray` of length 3 with all `true` values would result in `07` being stored into the database, denoting all three columns in a row between the two files matched.   Likewise, `02` would be stored if the first and third column did not match, but the second column did.

Expanded Example results:

| `BitArray` Values | Hex String Value | Binary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `new BitArray(new bool[3] { false, false, false})` | `00` | 0000 0000 |
| `new BitArray(new bool[3] { false, false, true})` | `01` | 0000 0001 |
| `new BitArray(new bool[3] { false, true, false})` | `02` | 0000 0010 |
| `new BitArray(new bool[3] { false, true, true})` | `03` | 0000 0011 |
| `new BitArray(new bool[3] { true, false, false})` | `04` | 0000 0100 |
| `new BitArray(new bool[3] { true, false, true})` | `05` | 0000 0101 |
| `new BitArray(new bool[3] { true, true, false})` | `06` | 0000 0110 |
| `new BitArray(new bool[3] { true, true, true })` | `07` | 0000 0111 |

You could even factor out the `BitArray` completely if wanted and instead use the `byte[]` everywhere.  The only changes I had to make to the SQL portion of the code was to update `DbType` to be `DbType.String` and the `Value` to be that of my hexadecimal variable.