# golang - ceil function like php?

Tags: go, ceil

I want to return the least integer value greater than or equal to integer division. So I used `math.ceil`, but can not get the value I want.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    var pagesize int = 10
    var length  int = 43

    d := float64(length / pagesize)
    page := int(math.Ceil(d))

    fmt.Println(page)
    // output 4 not 5
}
```

http://golang.org/pkg/math/#Ceil

http://play.golang.org/p/asHta1HkO_

What is wrong?
Thanks.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The line

```
d := float64(length / pagesize)
```

transforms to float the result of the division. Since the division itself is integer division, it results in 4, so d = 4.0 and `math.Ceil(d)` is 4.

Replace the line with

```
d := float64(length) / float64(pagesize)
```

and you'll have `d=4.3` and `int(math.Ceil(d))=5`.

Comment: No! just converting first operand is important and determinant.

Answer (score 18):

Avoiding floating point operations (for performance and clarity):

```
x, y := length, pagesize
q := (x + y - 1) / y;
```

for `x >= 0` and `y > 0`.

Or to avoid overflow of `x+y`:

```
q := 1 + (x - 1) / y
```

It's the same as the C++ version: [Fast ceiling of an integer division in C / C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745074/fast-ceiling-of-an-integer-division-in-c-c)

Comment: Worth noting that (at least on my 2014 MacBook Pro with a 2.5GHz i7) this is only about 17% faster than the `float64` / `math.Ceil` solution, and only with 32-bit integers—with `int64` it's about 24% slower. [Benchmark here](https://play.golang.org/p/75ybV6Efe0z)—although it doesn't actually work in the Go playground, I think b/c it doesn't have sufficient time resolution.

Still using this answer in my code for clarity, though.

Answer (score 13):

Convert length and pagesize to floats before the division:

```
d := float64(length) / float64(pagesize)
```

http://play.golang.org/p/FKWeIj7of5

Answer (score 5):

You can check the remainder to see if it should be raised to the next integer.

```
page := length / pagesize
if length % pagesize > 0 {
    page++
}
```