# Is there a name for "denominator minus one" part in division with rounding up?

Tags: language-agnostic, terminology, integer-division, ceil

This is the formula for integer division (for dividing `x` by `y`) with rounding up ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2745086/57428)):

```
q = (x + y - 1) / y;
```

`y` is called the denominator.

Is there any widely accepted term for `y - 1` in this formula?

Comment: what about subtraction?... denominator subtract one.

Comment: You might try asking on math.SE.