# Dividing 2 long values produces wrong output in c++

Tags: c++, long-integer, division

I am dividing 2 long values and use the ceiling of the result. However my code produces wrong output.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  long first = 100;
  long second = 1000;
  long output = ceil(first/second);
  cout<<"output = "<<output<<endl;
}
```

Here the expected output is

```
output = 1
```

actual output:

```
output = 0
```

Comment: `100/1000` is exactly 0. The ceil of that is still 0.

Comment: `first/second` This is integer division and the expected result is `0`. You may want to look at [Fast ceiling of an integer division in C / C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745074/fast-ceiling-of-an-integer-division-in-c-c).

Comment: @cigien, not sure what you mean. 100/1000 = 0.1

Comment: No 100/1000 is 0. With integer math there is no decimal point. 1/2 is zero as well.

Comment: @DenisShevchenko C++ is not Python 3.  An integer divided by an integer yields an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of order of evaluation of long output = ceil(first/second);

The first operation is first/second, 100/1000. Once you are using integer types (long is an integer) the result will be a long and it is truncated towards zero. 100/1000 =0

Then you have:
ceil(0) = 0 // as expected

long output = 0

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I did not realize the order of operations could affect the output like that. The solution turns out to be pretty simple as shown in the link @dxiv shared in the comments to my question.