# Math Round to always upper integer

Tags: c#

I need to find a division of two integers and round it to next upper integer

e.g  **x=7/y=5 = 2**; here x and y always greater than 0

This is my current code

```
 int roundValue = x % y > 0? x / y + 1: x / y;
```

Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921180/how-can-i-ensure-that-a-division-of-integers-is-always-rounded-up/926806

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You *could* use [`Math.Ceiling`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.ceiling)... but that will require converting to/from `double` values.

Another alternative is to use [`Math.DivRem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.divrem) to do both parts at the same time.

```cs
public static int DivideRoundingUp(int x, int y)
{
    // TODO: Define behaviour for negative numbers
    int remainder;
    int quotient = Math.DivRem(x, y, out remainder);
    return remainder == 0 ? quotient : quotient + 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Jone please add _out remainder_  as parameter to complete your answer

Answer (score 34):

Try `(int)Math.Ceiling(((double)x) / y)`

Answer (score 12):

All solutions looks too hard. For **upper value of x/y**, use this one

```
( x + y - 1 ) / y
```

Comment: 'add another group, but subtract one in case you already had a full group' - great idea. seems there's no problem so long as ints are positive. thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 4):

dunno what's better way or how to define a better way (if in terms of performance you have to run tests to see which will be faster), but here's my solution:

```
int roundValue = x / y + Convert.ToInt32(x%y>0);
```

p.s.

still have to deal somehow with neg. numbers... IMO this is the simplest.

Answer (score 3):

+0.5 will aways round to the higher.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ceil()` function.
It gives the upper value.

Comment: [ceil()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/ceil-ceilf-ceill?view=vs-2019) is part of C++. Equivalent for C# is [Math.Ceiling()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.ceiling?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `MidpointRounding` from `Math.Round`

In your case:

```
Math.Round(value, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

see more: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-6.0#system-math-round(system-double-system-midpointrounding)