# Why does -2 % 360 give -2 instead of 358 in c#

Tags: c#, .net, math

Microsoft Mathematics and Google's calculator give me 358 for -2 % 360, but C# and  windows calculator are outputting -2 ... which is the right answer ?

Comment: See "Quotient and remainder in programming languages" in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remainder

Comment: The simple definition is "the remainder of division". By that definition, -2 is probably more *right* -- after all, when you divide -2 by 360, you get a remainder of 2 (or -2, depending on how you look at it), and you definitely don't get 358. But for computing applications, 358 is often a more *useful* answer, which is why some languages choose to return it instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The C# compiler is doing the right thing according to the C# specification, which states that for integers:

> The result of `x % y` is the value produced by `x – (x / y) * y`.

Note that `(x/y)` always rounds *[towards zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921180/how-can-i-ensure-that-a-division-of-integers-is-always-rounded-up/926806#926806)*.

For the details of how remainder is computed for binary and decimal floating point numbers, see section 7.8.3 of the specification.

Whether this is the "right answer" for you depends on how you view the remainder operation. The remainder must satisfy the identity that:

```
dividend = quotient * divisor + remainder
```

I say that clearly -2 % 360 is -2. Why? Well, first ask yourself what the quotient is. How many times does 360 go into -2?  Clearly zero times! 360 doesn't go into -2 at all. If the quotient is zero then the remainder must be -2 in order to satisfy the identity. It would be strange to say that 360 goes into -2 a total of -1 times, with a remainder of 358, don't you think?

Comment: It all depends on what your perspective is. Your last paragraph is fine from one point of view. Another point of view would have the result of `a % b` in the range `0..b-1`. So I'm not sure that you can argue that the 358 brigade are wrong. I would say that most important is that the result is defined by the language spec. Yes, I'm looking at you C++!

Comment: A question: the C# compiler is obviously doing the right thing (since it pushes the correct operands onto the evaluation stack and calls `rem`). Given that, though, the compiler is relying on the defined behaviour of the `rem` IL instruction to ensure the correct C# behaviour. Would you consider this an "implementation" detail, insofar as that if the CLR team decided that `rem` behaved differently (not going to happen but play along,) the C# team would then have to request a special `rem2` IL instruction? Or is that the point: the language was designed to follow the IL spec?

Comment: @dlev: It is certainly no accident that there is an IL instruction for every basic C# operation on ints. The IL designers and C# designers back in 1999 were often sitting in the same room at the same time. Was C# designed to match IL? Was IL designed to match C#? Who knows? That's lost in the mists of time.

Answer (score 7):

> Which is the right answer?

Both answers are correct. It's merely a matter of convention which value is returned.

Answer (score 3):

Both, see [Modulo operation on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

Answer (score 3):

I found this very easy to understand explanation at [http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52343.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20180118003726/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52343.html)

```
There are different ways of thinking about remainders when you deal 
with negative numbers, and he is probably confusing two of them. The 
mod function is defined as the amount by which a number exceeds the 
largest integer multiple of the divisor that is not greater than that 
number. In this case, -340 lies between -360 and -300, so -360 is the 
greatest multiple LESS than -340; we subtract 60 * -6 = -360 from -340 
and get 20:

-420 -360 -300 -240 -180 -120  -60   0   60   120  180  240  300  360
--+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+--
       | |                                                    |  |
   -360| |-340                                             300|  |340
       |=|                                                    |==|
        20                                                     40

Working with a positive number like 340, the multiple we subtract is 
smaller in absolute value, giving us 40; but with negative numbers, we 
subtract a number with a LARGER absolute value, so that the mod 
function returns a positive value. This is not always what people 
expect, but it is consistent.

If you want the remainder, ignoring the sign, you have to take the 
absolute value before using the mod function.
```

Doctor Peterson, The Math Forum
[http://mathforum.org/dr.math/](https://web.archive.org/web/20171226054714/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/)

Answer (score 0):

IMO, -2 is much easier to understand and code with.  If you divide -2 by 360, your answer is 0 remainder -2 ... just as dividing 2 by 360 is 0 remainder 2.  It's not as natural to consider that 358 is also the remainder of -2 mod 360.

Comment: I've been programming for 20 years and found that when I do N % M, I *always* want a result in the range 0..M-1, so -2 % 360 should be 358. That said, most languages don't work that way so I write a special modulus function to compensate. Why is this natural? Well, there are 360 degrees in a circle. If you want to ensure all angles are in the range 0..360, you naturally write `angle % 360`. But you soon realize it doesn't work for negative angles.

Answer (score 0):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation):

> if the remainder is nonzero, there are two possible choices for the
>   remainder, one negative and the other positive, and there are also two
>   possible choices for the quotient. Usually, in number theory, the
>   positive remainder is always chosen, but programming languages choose
>   depending on the language and the signs of a and n.[2] However, Pascal
>   and Algol68 do not satisfy these conditions for negative divisors, and
>   some programming languages, such as C89, don't even define a result if
>   either of n or a is negative.