# Rounding in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, rounding

Sorry for such a uninteresting question, but I can't figure it out. Using c# in a silverlight app I want the result of 13/8 to be 1.63. I can get it to 1.62 or 1.625, but not the required 1.63.  Would anyone please be kind enough to show me how? Many thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921180/how-can-i-ensure-that-a-division-of-integers-is-always-rounded-up

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var rounded = Math.Round(number, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Your problem is that by default, `Math.Round()` use the "banker's rounding" that in case the number to round is halfway between two others (e.g. `1.625`) it is rounded toward the nearest even number (e.g. `1.62`)

Comment: I have tried that but it generates the error 'can't access internal enum 'Midpointrounding' here.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot you're in silverlight... have a look here: http://anderly.com/2009/08/08/silverlight-midpoint-rounding-solution/