# calling javascript function from an android activity

Tags: javascript, android, html

I wan to call a javascript function from an android activity but it doesn't seem to work.
I have used the android webview function webview.loadUrl("javascript:function()"); 
This is my android code:

```
package com.example.web;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    WebView webview;
    int i=30;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
        webview.loadUrl("javascript:change(i)");

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

This is my html code:

```
 <html>
<body>
<div id="texta">text</div>
<script>

function change(num){
document.getElementById("texta").innerHTML=num;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

It's likely your page isn't fully loaded by the time you're trying to execute the javascript. Can you try:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl("javascript:change(i)");
    }
});
```

Comment: I think that might be my problem. I will try it now.

Comment: I tried using the function without passing any argument and manually set the value in the javascript section and it worked fine. But when i pass the variable i to the function it doesn't not work.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks! Tho I think the function will be called everytime the page loads, even for a different URL, say I click on a search result, the function will get called again when the page loads whether it exists or not. To fix that you could use if or switch statements to call the javascript function depending on the url string.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    webview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    webview.loadUrl("javascript:change("+String.valueOf(i)+")");

}
```

Comment: Please flesh out your answer.

Comment: Edited answer, check it :)

Comment: That you didn't try very hard.

Comment: Explain WHY you suggest the answer you're suggesting.

Comment: You don't see any change from the code at the question and the my answer or NOT? A programer can easy see the different and WHY of this answer. Any other problem?

Comment: Yours is a mediocre answer as it is. Just so you know. This, by contrast, is a very high quality answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921180/how-can-i-ensure-that-a-division-of-integers-is-always-rounded-up/926806#926806

Comment: A simple solution don't need to explain to long like your link, right? Just you think so :)

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
String URL = "file:///android_asset/filename.html";
webviewBrowser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(webview.loadUrl(URL));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this :

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:change(i)");
```

to this

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript:change(" + i +")");
```

the way you have write it the "i" is not the variable "i" from your java code but just a String named "i".

Answer (score 0):

What is "i", If "i" is a number then Specify the Number, if "i" is a character then kindly enclose it in double Quotes, you are calling a method of some arguments, so kindly correct your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

try
webview.loadUrl("javascript:change(\""+i"\")");

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   final Activity MyActivity = this;
   text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.textValue);
   Show=(Button)findViewById(R.id.textButton);
   webView= (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
   getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS,
                                    Window.PROGRESS_VISIBILITY_ON);
   webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
   public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

   MyActivity .setTitle("Loading...");
     MyActivity .setProgress(progress * 100);

     if (progress == 100)
     MyActivity .setTitle("Android Dhina");
    }
   });
     webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
     webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");

     webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/web.html");

     Show.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
      {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) 
       {
         webView.loadUrl("javascript:callFromAndroidActivity
                          (\""+text.getText().toString()+"\")"); }
        });
```