# Is there a name or built in c# function for this type of division

Tags: c#, math

I have this extension method, but I don't know whether there is already a built in operator for it or if there is a name for it:

```
public static class IntegerExtensions
{
    public static int DivideWholeAndPartial(this int total, int divisor)
    {
        return (total / divisor) +
               ((total % divisor) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
    }
}
```

Essentially if the total divides equally, then that is returned.  If there are any remainders it is rounded up - i.e. include partials as a whole.  Kind of like a "How many One litre bottles are needed to hold 3.5 litres of water" problem.

Am I missing any built in C# methods?  Is there a name for this?

Comment: Is `total` and `divisor` both guaranteed to be positive?

Comment: Hmmm, good point....now where did I put my `uint`...

Comment: @EricLippert Technically, that would be not half, but whole seven eights of cases (mixed signs cover three quarters, plus the overflow breaks half of the "both positives" quarter). Yet the simplicity of the darn little trick trumps its (in)correctness time and time again. I guess negative 3.5 liters of water are too hard to obtain, and 2147483647 liters is too much for most applications to consider :-)

Comment: @EricLippert But no-one expressed the problem in terms of bottles of water :)

Comment: The answer of Ian Nelson in the linked duplicate may be further simplified as `return 1+(total-1) / divisor;`.

Answer (score 5):

I think `Ceiling` does what you want:

```
return (int)Math.Ceiling((double)total / (double)divisor);
```

.. but I think you'll have to keep your extension method, as there isn't a built-in method that does this.

Comment: I think `Ceiling` is probably the term I should have thought of, but I suppose I was thinking about pure Integer division!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's an "atomic" operation (I may be misusing that word) for both the division and the rounding. However, the rounding part of it would be a Ceiling function. [`System.Math.Ceiling`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be the normal way to do that in C#:

```
return (int)Math.Ceiling((double)total / (double)divisor);
```

Comment: I think Ceiling is probably the term I should have thought of, but I suppose I was thinking about pure Integer division!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static class IntegerExtensions
{
    public static int DivideWholeAndPartial(this int total, int divisor)
    {
        return (int)Math.Ceiling((double)total / (double)divisor);
    }
}
```