# Math.round in asp.net return 76854.05 instead of 76854.06 ? how to solve this. how to get 76854.06 value using math.round function???

Tags: c#, asp.net

- Math.round in asp.net return 76854.05 instead of 76854.06 ?
- how to solve this.
- how to get 76854.06 value using math.round function???

Comment: What is the number you are rounding?

Comment: 1493501.1*5/100*100/100

Comment: Have you looked at the *Note to Callers* on the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/75ks3aby)?

Comment: please don't write full question in title.

Comment: [Here is an Ideone version](http://ideone.com/oCfrNZ).

Comment: Maybe this solves it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921180/how-can-i-ensure-that-a-division-of-integers-is-always-rounded-up/926806#926806

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double type should be used just for scientific calculation, for currencies, and types where rounding is important, use decimal instead:

```
var foobar = Math.Round(1493501.1m * 5 / 100 * 100 / 100, 2);
```

m suffix stands for decimal type.

Comment: In particular midpoint rules make little sense when rouding `double` numbers to 1 or more decimals. Actually, both `Math.Round(74675.055, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)` and `Math.Round(74675.055, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven)` round ***down*** to a number that looks like `74675.05`. The "midpoint" is not really realizable. Use `decimal`. With `decimal`, both `Math.Round(74675.055m, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)` and `Math.Round(74675.055m, 2, MidpointRounding.ToEven)` round ***up*** to `74675.06m` which is an exact number.