# class can not deal with *args properly

Tags: python, class

I wrote a class in which has a function taking several inputs by `*args`, however the running result proves that it only takes arguments from the second one, as if `self` takes the first one, here's a simplified code:

```
class incorrect():
    def itera(self, *args):
        for i in args:
            print(i)

a = incorrect
a.itera(12, 23, 34)
```

And the output, `12` is lost:

```
23
34
```

What is the problem? How can I fix that?

Comment: How do these answers have so many upvotes on a question that is a blatant off topic typo?

Comment: Because noone found a duplicate before the answers were posted?! :)

Comment: @MSeifert It's not a duplicate... it's just a typo

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Well that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534345/typeerror-missing-1-required-positional-argument-self seems like a valid duplicate target...

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I wasn't sure what to search for a question like this, so I decided to answer. +5 is a little ridiculous though for such a simple question.

Comment: @MSeifert Err, I've already VTC as off topic, so please do the honours.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I wish some of my half decent answers would get 5 upvotes every now and then ;-(

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ ikr. Theres been answers that I work on for half an hour that just get an accept; if that. I think the +5 so came in within like a minute. People are weird.

Comment: And this isn't really a typo is it? It could be due to a misunderstanding of syntax.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Anyone with an unsung hero badge can appreciate what you said. People can be [really](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45164645/how-to-separate-an-integer-into-two-addends/45164689#45164689) ... [weird](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46150875/4909087) sometimes, because of how subjective a "good answer" is.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes, not a typo indeed, I didn't fully understand the difference between `a = someClass` and `a = smoeClass()` until that question...

Comment: @AmarthGûl OK good. I would review creating instances if I were you though, even if these answers helped. It's quite an important thing to have a good grasp of.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ The more I use this site, the more I appreciate timing's role. It's sad, but sometimes timing Trump's quality.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Can we take a moment to also appreciate the fact that one of the most pedestrian answers I've written is also one of my most highly voted ones? x(

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Ya, I wasn't going to comment, but getting a 91 for showing the use of ceiling and round is pretty... generous. Oh well, we all get those sometimes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you use it on the class and so `self` is `12` and `args` is `[33, 34]`. You can fix it by creating an instance:

```
a = incorrect()
a.itera(12, 23, 34)
```

Or you could omit `self` in the signature and use decorator `@staticmethod`:

```
@staticmethod
def itera(*args):
    for i in args:
        print(i)
```

Or you could make it `classmethod`:

```
@classmethod
def itera(cls, *args):
    for i in args:
        print(i)
```

Comment: I haven't downvoted but you could `print(self)` inside the function to "prove" your argument. Maybe also elaborate on the *why* `self=12` if you call it on the class :)

Comment: I guess it's not the *best* explication you could have provided. But it's the right one anyway.

Comment: Instead of omitting `self` (don't do that, you will have a similar problem if you call it on an instance) make it a `@staticmethod`.

Comment: I was just referring to your "Or you could omit self in the signature". That's bad advise. If it shouldn't have `self` it should be a staticmethod, if it should have `cls` it should be a classmethod.

Answer (score 5):

You're calling the method on the class itself, not an instance of the class. Create an instance, then call the method on it:

```
a = incorrect() # Add () to create instance
a.itera(12, 23, 34)
```

When you call it on the class itself, it acts as a static method, and `self` is no longer implicitly passed since there *is* no `self` to pass.