# Check if two values are both non-negative or both negative

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a pair of integer values, I need to check if both are non-negative or both are negative.

The trivial way is:

```
def func(a, b):
    return (a >= 0 and b >= 0) or (a < 0 and b < 0)
```

But I am looking for something "neater", which I believe to be possible, so I came up with this:

```
def func(a, b):
    return (a >= 0) ^ (b >= 0) == 0
```

However, this one feels a little "obscure to the average reader".

Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Multiply them and test against 0:

```
def func(a, b):
    return a * b >= 0
```

Comment: Thank you. Is this agnostic to integer size? I am dealing with extremely large values.

Comment: @goodvibration yes, python ints have no limit besides your system memory.

Comment: @goodvibration Python integers are always arbitrary precision, so no overflow.

Comment: @monamona Hmm, here's [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45164645/4909087) for which I though the answer to be obvious, but apparently not, judging by the votes on the accepted answer :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I correct myself. You are an absolute genious! Maybe you are not concerned by "déformation professionelle"...

Answer (score 3):

This is Python.  We're not about the most concise efficient possible way to do things in all cases - that's for the C++ lads to do.

If `(a >= 0 and b >= 0) or (a < 0 and b < 0)` is "fast enough", (which would surprise me if not the case), then stick with it.  It works, and is VERY obvious what it does.

For either your second solution, or @coldspeed's, I personally would have to write some stuff down on paper to figure out what it's doing, unless the function name was a LOT better than `func`.