# Why does this ulong divided by ulong give me 0?

Tags: c#, types, ulong

I am grabbing total RAM of a computer system and available RAM and trying to work out what percentage is available.

I am using the following code:

```
double percent = my.Info.AvailablePhysicalMemory / my.Info.TotalPhysicalMemory;
```

and have also tried:

```
decimal percent = my.Info.AvailablePhysicalMemory / my.Info.TotalPhysicalMemory;
```

I am sure it's an issue with the type but I am unsure why both methods give a result of 0.

The actual values are Total: 17072574464 and Available: 8746000384. The values come back from the system cast as ulong. So what does percent always equal 0? If I put the numbers in directly it works fine. Just can't use the ulong variables - hence why I am sure it's my lack of experience with types in C# that is the problem.

Comment: Integer math. Convert one or both operands to double (or decimal, depending on which line you've kept) before or while dividing.

Comment: Nothing to do with ulong:  `10 / 11 = 0`

Comment: @TaW 10 / 11 != 0 on a calculator. It was that I was working with ulong (integer) values as they were incorrectly cast for what I was trying to do. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: Indeed c# is not a calculator but a language. You have to understand the rules and it will reward you by doing ~anything you want..

Comment: I *really* wish the C# compiler warned about this. "Late conversion" is a common error amongst both novice and experienced programmers. You also see it in multiplication, where we have `long r = a * b;` where `a` and `b` are integers big enough to overflow into a long when multiplied, but that's not what happens.

Comment: If the subject of how people get integer division wrong interests you, there are some good examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921180/how-can-i-ensure-that-a-division-of-integers-is-always-rounded-up/926806#926806

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to divide an integer by an integer, which always rounds down. You need to convert to a floating point number before you divide; for example:

```cs
double percent = my.Info.AvailablePhysicalMemory * 1.0 / my.Info.TotalPhysicalMemory;
```

Comment: `double(my.Info.AvailablePhysicalMemory)` doesn't compile, did you mean `(double)my.Info.AvailablePhysicalMemory`?

Comment: You can also write `1.0 * my.Info.AvailablePhysicalMemory / my.Info.TotalPhysicalMemory;`

Comment: Thanks, I brainfarted on how C# casting looks. I'd originally used `1.0` but switched to an explicit cast because I figured someone would peg it as bad style. :P  (Also @SystemX17 I'm not a 'he')

Comment: Have removed the gendered comment fluffy. My apologies.