# Sum of Array after k operations

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I got an interview question where I need to do k operation on an array and get the sum of final array.

For each iteration, any random element needs to be picked, divide it by 2 and replace the the value with existing value in array.

arr = [20,10,7]

Pick 7, divide it by 2 and replace 7 with ceil value of the result , output for first iteration will be

[20,10,4]

I wrote the code which is working fine but apparently it is not an optimal solution. It is taking a lot of time for large input.I found a few solutions on stack overflow in other languages but not in iOS related languages.

How can I achieve an optimal solution?

```
    func minimumSum(numbers:[Int] , iterations:Int) -> Int {
    var arr = numbers
    guard  arr.count > 1 else{
        return 0
    }

    var count = 0
    repeat{
        if let randomNumber = arr.max(){
           // print(randomNumber)
            let divided:Int = Int((Double(randomNumber) / 2).rounded())
            let indexOfNumber = arr.firstIndex(of: randomNumber)
            arr[indexOfNumber!] = divided
            count = count + 1
            print(count)
        }
    }while count < iterations

    return arr.reduce(0,+)


}
```

Comment: How is `arr.max()` a random number?

Comment: For some reason randomNumber wasnt working for me. so i tried with the maximum number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One significant thing that slows your code down is that in each iteration, you are finding the maximum of the array, and searching for the index of the maximum using `firstIndex(of:)`. These are all operations that takes longer as the array gets longer.

You wouldn't have to do these things if you were actually finding a random number from the array. You would just find a random index of the array, and get the number at that index, and since you have the index already, you don't have to use `firstIndex(of:)`.

```
func minimumSum(numbers:[Int] , iterations:Int) -> Int {
    var arr = numbers
    for _ in 0..<iterations {
        guard let randomIndex = arr.indices.randomElement() else {
           return 0
        }
        let randomNumber = numbers[randomIndex]
        let divided = (randomNumber + 1) / 2
        arr[randomIndex] = divided
    }
    return arr.reduce(0,+)
}
```

Comment: This is pretty similar to what I was gonna suggest except the calculation. `number / 2 + (number.isMultiple(of: 2) ? 0 : 1)` I was about to post `var numbers = numbers` `(0..<iterations).forEach { _ in` `if let index = numbers.indices.randomElement() {` `let number = numbers[index]` `numbers[index] = number / 2 + (number.isMultiple(of: 2) ? 0 : 1)` `}` `}` `return numbers.reduce(0, +)`

Comment: @LeoDabus, why not `numbers[index] = (number + 1) / 2` ?

Comment: @vacawama Ah I knew there's a trick like that, but I just couldn't come up with it! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot. though I am not getting the intended output. My actual issue about time got resolved greatly.

Comment: @vacawama another option is `number / 2 + number % 2`

Comment: @LeoDabus, yes that works also, but is 3 operations instead of 2.

Comment: @vacawama yes but that ```number / 2 + number % 2``` also works for negative numbers, to make your ```( number + 1 ) / 2``` work for negatives you also need to add one more operation e.g. ```( number >= 0 ? ( number + 1 ) : ( number - 1 ) ) / 2```

Comment: @skaak, that's a good point with negative numbers.  `n / 2 + n % 2` does give the same results as `Int((Double(n) / 2).rounded())` which is OP's formula.

Comment: @skaak, that might still be the incorrect result if the original problem specified to divide by 2 and take the `ceil`, because `ceil(-0.5)` is `0`, not `-1`.

Comment: @vacawama yes I assume here it is normal round away from 0 and have only the OP example 7 / 2 = 4 to go by. I was wondering how you'd do this if e.g. it was divide 3 or 4 or ... then I noted how sign might influence the outcome. I think at some lower level you should be able to use just 2 operations e.g. if you shift bits or have access to C's ```div``` or maybe there is some clever way that we are all missing here. Maybe ```( number + signum( number ) ) / 2``` is the way to go? Then it only works for 2 but you could easily fix that.

Comment: @vacawama wait that actually does not work - how about ```( n + n.signum() * d / 2 ) / d``` and for performance you can precompute the ```d/2```

Comment: @vacawama also + 1 before division would overflow when used with integer max. There is a good [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/926806/2303865) about this from Eric Lippert

Comment: @vacawama https://gist.github.com/leodabus/a0e0a4f31f019b99e5f2026c5b17cc5c