# ceil conterpart for Math.floorDiv in Java?

Tags: java, math, java-8

Is there any `ceil` counterpart for [`Math.floorDiv()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floorDiv-long-long-)

How to calculate it fastest way with what we have?

**UPDATE**

The code for `floorDiv()` is follows:

```
 public static long floorDiv(long x, long y) {
        long r = x / y;
        // if the signs are different and modulo not zero, round down
        if ((x ^ y) < 0 && (r * y != x)) {
            r--;
        }
        return r;
    }
```

Can we code `ceil` the similar way?

**UPDATE 2**

I saw this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7446742/258483 but it seems to have too many unnecessary operations.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is none in the `Math` class, but you can easily calculate it

```
long ceilDiv(long x, long y){
    return -Math.floorDiv(-x,y);
}
```

For example, `ceilDiv(1,2)` = `-floorDiv(-1,2)` =`-(-1)`= 1 (correct answer).

Comment: Anyway I like your answer most.

Comment: That's what I call a neat solution!

Answer (score 3):

I'd also just use the negation of floorMod, but if you are going to define your own function, you could simply adapt the above code:

```
public static int ceilDiv(int x, int y) {
    int r = x / y;
    // if the signs are the same and modulo not zero, round up
    if ((x ^ y) >= 0 && (r * y != x)) r++;
    return r;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `floorDiv` function and fiddle with that:

```
int ceilDiv(int x, int y) {
    return Math.floorDiv(x, y) + (x % y == 0 ? 0 : 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 18, `Math.ceilDiv` is available, see https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#ceilDiv(int,int)