# Java stream reduce to lists of fixed size

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I have a list of items, say..

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

What I want is to have lists of size 3

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12], [13, 14]]
```

How to do this with java streams?

```
list.stream()
    .reduce( /* what do I do here? */ )
    .forEach( l -> /* l.size() == 3 */);
```

Comment: Argh... almost wrote an answer. The answers in that old question do not produce java-8 stream as author wanted.

Comment: .. but the OP agreed to close this as a duplicate. So we can't do much more :-)

Comment: Ok, I see. Fine then.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29273705/how-to-paginate-a-list-of-objects-in-java-8/29274438#29274438

Comment: Posted my version to that question. Probably somebody will like it.

Comment: I could do `Lists.partition(list, 3).stream()` which resolved my issue. But you are right, that it not directly answered my question. Should we therefore reopen the question? I don't think so. Sorry for any inconvenience, and thanks for your effort!