# Spring Data JPA Repositories with Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, spring, java-8, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Lets say I have the following repository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("select u from User u")
    Stream<User> streamAllPaged(Pageable pageable);
}
```

And I want to perform a search:

```
public Page<User> findAllUsers(Pageable page) {

    Page<User> page = null;
    try (Stream<User> users = userRepository.streamAllPaged(page)) {
            Set<User> users = users.filter(u -> user.getName().equals("foo"))
                    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
            //create page from set?
    }

}
```

Obviously I could use a sublist and manually insert page sizes etc but I guess that there should be a more "standard" way to do this?

Comment: I would have thought `Collectors.partitioningBy` could help, but without access to a position in the stream in don't see how.

Comment: If you don't mind using another stream, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29273705/how-to-paginate-a-list-of-objects-in-java-8) has the answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'd argue your use case doesn't make too much sense here. If you want to end up with a `Page` of results eventually, starting with a `Stream` is just inefficient. You could easily achieve your expected end result with this:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

  Page<User> findByName(String name, Pageable pageable);
}
```

That'd make sure you only read the amount of names you initially request. Using a `Stream` here is completely subverting the point as filtering on the `Stream` will require *all* `User` instances to be loaded into memory just to invoke the predicate. You definitely want to let the database do that only return the values that match in the first place.