# how to always round up to the next integer

Tags: c#, language-agnostic, rounding

i am trying to find total pages in building a pager on a website (so i want the result to be an integer.  i get a list of records and i want to split into 10 per page (the page count)

when i do this:

```
list.Count() / 10
```

or

```
list.Count() / (decimal)10
```

and the `list.Count() =12`, i get a result of `1`.

How would I code it so i get `2` in this case (the remainder should always add `1`)

Comment: (list.Count()+9)/10 - that's the best :)

Comment: Math.Round(8.28, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)

Answer (score 193, accepted):

```
Math.Ceiling((double)list.Count() / 10);
```

Comment: converting int to floating point is just bad (and slow) for such a simple operation

Comment: It's not converting from int to floating point, it's telling the function whether the value is a `decimal` or a `double`, as the type cannot be determined automatically.

Comment: @Rob, you do.. twice, int->floating point(double)->int. it requires double flush of the CPU, the solution is the worst possible correct (for int but not long) one

Comment: The difference in execution times for 1 million cycles is 0.01ms. I think the extra readability for such a negligible increase in processing time is worth it.

Comment: @Rob - The difference is not simply in the floating point conversion, you also have additional function call overhead for the call to Ceiling().  This isn't "extra readability" it's "extra work" and is *not* the right way to do this.  This question gets asked in myriad ways over and over again on SO and there is a better solution that involves no typecasting and no additional functional call.  New programmers need to learn to do it the right way.  It turns out doing it correctly is quite readable and seeing someone do it wrong calls all of their code into question.

Comment: @Rob, you sure all your code was not dead code eliminated? Do you know how to write proper micro-benchmark (almost all developers don't know, so it's a fair question)

Comment: I'll point out also that your solution requires Math.Ceiling() to be available.  The solution utilizing knowledge of basic integer math is completely portable.

Comment: @bestsss Yes, I'm sure the it was not dead-code eliminated.

Comment: @Rob, I've got some free time and decided to hook on the miraculous benchmark of your and wrote my own. Having some **HUGE** differences between the tests. I write another answer just for the benchmark

Comment: @par, Added some benchmark results...

Comment: This is how: Math.Round(8.28, 0, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)

Comment: @Andreas Using Math.Round will also require unnecessary conversion to double.

Comment: These guys are complaining about benchmarks for a paging formula... Rob's answer is best man.  It's clean and simple and you're not processing this hundreds of times in some iteration... Once you have a list you simply need to know the number of pages, this type conversion fuss from int to double to int is for nanoseconds of time that will add up to a possible split second one day.  Not worth the time to even write this comment in response honestly.  Sometimes even milliseconds added here or there is worth simplicity.

Answer (score 91):

`(list.Count() + 9) / 10`

Everything else here is either overkill or simply wrong (except for [bestsss' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4892486/312594), which is awesome).  We do ***not*** want the overhead of a function call (`Math.Truncate()`, `Math.Ceiling()`, etc.) when simple math is enough.

---

OP's question generalizes ([*pigeonhole principle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle)) to:

> How many boxes do I need to store `x` objects if only `y` objects fit into each box?

The solution:

1. derives from the realization that the last box *might* be partially empty, and
2. is `(x + y - 1) ÷ y` using [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html).

You'll recall from 3<sup>rd</sup> grade math that *integer division* is what we're doing when we say `5 ÷ 2 = 2`.

*Floating-point division* is when we say `5 ÷ 2 = 2.5`, but we ***don't*** want that here.

Many programming languages support integer division.  In languages derived from C, you get it automatically when you divide `int` types (`short`, `int`, `long`, etc.).  The remainder/fractional part of any division operation is simply dropped, thus:

`5 / 2 == 2`

Replacing our original question with `x = 5` and `y = 2` we have:

> How many boxes do I need to store 5 objects if only 2 objects fit into each box?

The answer should now be obvious: `3 boxes` -- the first two boxes hold two objects each and the last box holds one.

```
(x + y - 1) ÷ y =
(5 + 2 - 1) ÷ 2 =
6 ÷ 2 =
3
```

So for the original question, `x = list.Count()`, `y = 10`, which gives the solution using no additional function calls:

`(list.Count() + 9) / 10`

Comment: Either this is wrong, or the following statement is false:
113 + 4 / 5 = 23,4

Comment: Your statement is false (it's actually 23, which is what we want).  See my revised answer.

Comment: Instead of *rounding* the quotient to next whole integer, I believe you should pick its integer part instead: `Math.Truncate((decimal)((list.Count() + 9 ) / 10))`

Comment: @EfranCobisi You're correct in principle, but picking the integer part happens automatically here (follow the *integer division* link in my answer to see why), so a call to `Math.Truncate()` is not only redundant, it adds computational overhead we want to explicitly avoid.

Comment: great explanation

Comment: Why this answer has not been more recognized is beyond me. This is by far the most elegant solution.

Comment: 113 + 4 / 5 is actually 113.8 or 114

Comment: @mr5 Is correct that parentheses _definitely_ matter here.  `113 + 4 / 5` when written without parentheses is interpreted as `113 + (4 / 5)` by the compiler, and equals either 113.8 when using floating point types or _113_ when integer types are used (because `4 / 5 == 0` with integer division).  The original comment should have been written as `(113 + 4) / 5`, which is 23.4 with floating point types or 23 with integer types.

Comment: you are right, simple math is enough for this problem. Thanks for the answer, worked like a charm for my case as well

Comment: Unless `list.Count() + 9` overflows, in which case you get a negative answer.

Comment: @ClementCherlin Overflow is a problem inherent to any calculation that uses fixed bit-width hardware registers. It has nothing to do with the correctness of this method and for the most part is a non-issue unless you're programming something for which arbitrary precision integers are really required. Honestly, if you have a list returning a `count()` that doesn't fit into a 64-bit integer (or really even a 32-bit integer), you have bigger problems.

Comment: @par I respectfully disagree. Not accounting for integer overflow in a general-purpose integer routine is a bug. How can you know whether it's a "non-issue" when you have no way of knowing in what programs this answer may be used? The history of software development is littered with serious, harmful (even deadly) integer overflow bugs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow#Examples . The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4846533 is unconditionally correct.

Comment: @ClementCherlin I said it's "for the most part" a non-issue. It does help to know your problem domain. For example, the answer you linked as "unconditionally correct" calls `list.Count()` twice. Are you sure it's thread safe and the list didn't change between calls? That's a problem domain assumption. I suppose you could require we store `list.Count()` in a temporary and use three lines of code everywhere for this simple calculation, or require a mutex, or add some other complication... The point of my answer is to show how to do this using simple math. One function call, two operators, done.

Comment: @par If your list is being concurrently modified the answer may be wrong, regardless of the method of computation. Integer overflow, on the other hand, is inherent to the method of computation.

Comment: @ClementCherlin You are correct, this method can overflow. If one's use case is such that overflow has any reasonable chance of occurring then of course it makes sense to trade speed for safety. In such cases an alternate method (such as the answer you linked above) should be used. Caveat emptor.

Answer (score 24):

#### A proper benchmark or how the number may lie

Following the argument about `Math.ceil(value/10d)` and  `(value+9)/10` I ended up coding a proper non-dead code, non-interpret mode benchmark.
I've been telling that writing micro benchmark is not an easy task. The code below illustrates this:

```
00:21:40.109 starting up....
00:21:40.140 doubleCeil: 19444599
00:21:40.140 integerCeil: 19444599
00:21:40.140 warming up...
00:21:44.375 warmup doubleCeil: 194445990000
00:21:44.625 warmup integerCeil: 194445990000
00:22:27.437 exec doubleCeil: 1944459900000, elapsed: 42.806s
00:22:29.796 exec integerCeil: 1944459900000, elapsed: 2.363s
```

The benchmark is in Java since I know well how Hotspot optimizes and ensures it's a fair result. With such results, no statistics, noise or anything can taint it.

*Integer ceil is insanely much faster.*

The code

```
package t1;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import java.util.Random;

public class Div {
    static int[] vals;

    static long doubleCeil(){
        int[] v= vals;
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<v.length;i++){
            int value = v[i];
            sum+=Math.ceil(value/10d);
        }
        return sum;
    }

    static long integerCeil(){      
        int[] v= vals;
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<v.length;i++){
            int value = v[i];
            sum+=(value+9)/10;
        }
        return sum;     
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        vals = new  int[7000];
        Random r= new Random(77);
        for (int i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
            vals[i] = r.nextInt(55555);
        }
        log("starting up....");

        log("doubleCeil: %d", doubleCeil());
        log("integerCeil: %d", integerCeil());
        log("warming up...");       

        final int warmupCount = (int) 1e4;
        log("warmup doubleCeil: %d", execDoubleCeil(warmupCount));
        log("warmup integerCeil: %d", execIntegerCeil(warmupCount));

        final int execCount = (int) 1e5;

        {       
        long time = System.nanoTime();
        long s = execDoubleCeil(execCount);
        long elapsed = System.nanoTime() - time;
        log("exec doubleCeil: %d, elapsed: %.3fs",  s, BigDecimal.valueOf(elapsed, 9));
        }

        {
        long time = System.nanoTime();
        long s = execIntegerCeil(execCount);
        long elapsed = System.nanoTime() - time;
        log("exec integerCeil: %d, elapsed: %.3fs",  s, BigDecimal.valueOf(elapsed, 9));            
        }
    }

    static long execDoubleCeil(int count){
        long sum = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
            sum+=doubleCeil();
        }
        return sum;
    }


    static long execIntegerCeil(int count){
        long sum = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
            sum+=integerCeil();
        }
        return sum;
    }

    static void log(String msg, Object... params){
        String s = params.length>0?String.format(msg, params):msg;
        System.out.printf("%tH:%<tM:%<tS.%<tL %s%n", new Long(System.currentTimeMillis()), s);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Great answer.  Assertions are one thing, proof is something else entirely.

Comment: good point, proof is something else

Answer (score 17):

This will also work:

```
c = (count - 1) / 10 + 1;
```

Comment: I like this most, very nice

Comment: I see multiple problems with your code, especially with numbers like 0 and 20(would return 3) or any larger number than 10.

Comment: @Rumplin, you are right about 0, but for 20 it returns 2 as expected.

Comment: You are right, it works ok for number > 0

Comment: A nice solution, but IMO this is less readable than using Math.Ceiling. At a glance it is not clear what the code is meant to be doing.

Comment: generally: (count + pageSize - 1) / pageSize

Comment: @Co7e you could add a comment. Efficiency is more valuable imo.

Answer (score 5):

I think the easiest way is to divide two integers and increase by one :

```
int r = list.Count() / 10;
r += (list.Count() % 10 == 0 ? 0 : 1);
```

No need of libraries or functions.

edited with the right code.

Comment: that doesn't work correctly when count % 10 ==0. i.e. returns 2 for 10

Comment: Not correct if list.Count() == 10 prior to the division.  Then you get 2 when 1 is correct.

Comment: Oops, missed that. You're right guys :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use Math.Ceiling

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.ceiling%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Check by using mod - if there is a remainder, simply increment the value by one.

Comment: The you have to do mod followed by a test followed by an increment (which is an add and a store).  Too expensive.  It's easier to do add then divide only (as expensive as mod).  No test required.

Answer (score 1):

Xform to double (and back) for a simple ceil?

`list.Count()/10 + (list.Count()%10 >0?1:0)` - this bad, div + mod

edit 1st:
on a 2n thought that's probably faster (depends on the optimization): div * mul (mul is faster than div and mod)

```
int c=list.Count()/10;
if (c*10<list.Count()) c++;
```

**edit2** scarpe all. forgot the most natural (adding 9 ensures rounding up for integers)

`(list.Count()+9)/10`