# How to round up in c#

Tags: c#, rounding

I want to round up always in c#, so for example, from 6.88 to 7, from 1.02 to 2, etc.

How can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to always round up to the next integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846493/how-to-always-round-up-to-the-next-integer)

Comment: Try to write Math. and look with enough attention to all the function you see

Comment: Incomplete specs. What should -1.02 become?

Comment: simple googling would have helped :)

Comment: yep, I googled, first on the list was this post... Thanks for asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I ensure that a division of integers is always rounded up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921180/how-can-i-ensure-that-a-division-of-integers-is-always-rounded-up)

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Use [`Math.Ceiling()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48.aspx)

```
double result = Math.Ceiling(1.02);
```

Comment: First one I saw. This is more clear than using awayfromzero. Thanks!

Comment: Clearer, and correct.  :)  `AwayFromZero` is used for something else, and would break for you in this case.

Comment: Is there an option that returns an `int` or `long` instead?

Comment: @KyleDelaney no, but you can easily cast it via `(int) Math.Ceiling(someDouble);`.

Comment: @henry.dv - I wonder why a rounding function would return a double to begin with

Comment: @KyleDelaney https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693468/why-math-ceiling-returns-double

Answer (score 30):

Use Math.Ceiling:
    `Math.Ceiling(value)`

Answer (score 14):

If negative values are present, **Math.Round** has additional options (*in .Net Core 3 or later*).

I did a benchmark(.Net 5/release) though and Math.Ceiling() is faster and more efficient.

```
Math.Round( 6.88, MidpointRounding.ToPositiveInfinity) ==> 7   (~23 clock cycles)
Math.Round(-6.88, MidpointRounding.ToPositiveInfinity) ==> -6  (~23 clock cycles)

Math.Round( 6.88, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)       ==> 7   (~23 clock cycles)
Math.Round(-6.88, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)       ==> -7  (~23 clock cycles)

Math.Ceiling( 6.88)                                    ==> 7   (~1 clock cycles)
Math.Ceiling(-6.88)                                    ==> -6  (~1 clock cycles)
```

Comment: Math.Round has the advantage that it has the possibility to round to a given amount of decimals. While this is not possible with Math.Ceiling!