# Calculate the number of columns given number of rows and limit of items per row

Tags: c#

I'm try to find a way to properly calculate the number of columns given the number of rows and the number of items per row.

For example:

I have 11 items I would like to lay in a table that has 2 rows and each row can only hold 5 items, so this means that the table should have 3 columns, 2 rows with 5 items each and 1 row with a single item.

I have already tried the following formula:

```
column_count = (item_count / row_count) + (item_count - row_count) / row_count
```

Which doesn't return the correct number of columns given certain item counts for example, given 16 items and a limit of 5 items per row, the formula should return 4 but it returns 5.

Comment: `int noofitems = 11;
int colcount = 5;
int rowsneeded = (int)noofitems/colcount + (int)noofitems%colcount;`

Comment: item_count % 5 > 0 ? item_count / 5 +  1 : item_count / 5;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just [round up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613444/how-to-round-up-in-c-sharp) to the next int after a none [interger division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851273/why-does-integer-division-in-c-sharp-return-an-integer-and-not-a-float).

```
var nbColumns =  Math.Ceiling( (double)nbItem / nbRow ) ;
```

16/5 = 3.2, round up to 4