# Rounding up a number to nearest multiple of 5

Tags: java, rounding

Does anyone know how to round up a number to its nearest multiple of 5?  I found an algorithm to round it to the nearest multiple of 10 but I can't find this one.

This does it for ten.

```
double number = Math.round((len + 5)/ 10.0) * 10.0;
```

Comment: What's the code you have for 10 look like? It should be reasonably straightforward to change 10 to 5.

Comment: What's the type of `len`? Is that an `int` or `double`?

Comment: it's a double. if i didn't initialize it as a double it would give me an error i think

Comment: `double number = Math.round((len + 2.5)/ 5.0) * 5.0;` ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to always round up to the next integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4846493/how-to-always-round-up-to-the-next-integer)

Comment: @bestsss The question doesn't say to round integers, does it?

Comment: @JuanMendes exactly, the question literally said `double`, and used 10.0

Comment: **See Also**: [Rounding numbers to specific multiples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10456564/1366033)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

```
int roundUp(int n) {
    return (n + 4) / 5 * 5;
}
```

Note - YankeeWhiskey's answer is rounding to the closest multiple, this is rounding up. Needs a modification if you need it to work for negative numbers.  Note that integer division followed by integer multiplication of the same number is the way to round down.

Comment: Why are we adding 4 to the number?

Comment: 4 === n-1
So you can replace it with "return (n + n - 1) / n * n;"

Answer (score 149):

To round to the nearest of any value:

```
int round(double value, int nearest) {
    return (int) Math.round(value / nearest) * nearest;
}
```

You can also replace `Math.round()` with either `Math.floor()` or `Math.ceil()` to make it always round down or always round up.

Comment: This is by far the best answer. It is universal, it will work for rounding to the nearest of any whole number (e.g. 2 or 5) or any fraction (e.g. 0.1 or 0.05).

Comment: But it must be edited to take and return doubles in order to work for fractional numbers

Comment: I'm not sure why this has so many votes when it doesn't actually compile

Comment: @dave.c It does compile.

Comment: @SamJakob When I compile it with Java 1.8.0_152 I get `error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from long to int`.  In order to get it to compile you need to either cast the result of `Math.round` or change the return type to `long`.

Comment: @dave.c My bad - I didn't notice that, I only used it in a function that returns a double.

Comment: Props for giving the correct answer. Zero props for using unreadable variable names (double i , double v).

Comment: nitpicking: how do you round to the nearest "Foo" ? shouldn't say "any value", perhaps "any integer value" ?

Answer (score 13):

I think I have it, thanks to [Amir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/690553/amir-pashazadeh)

```
double round( double num, int multipleOf) {
  return Math.floor((num + multipleOf/2) / multipleOf) * multipleOf;
}
```

Here's the code I ran

```
class Round {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("3.5 round to 5: " + Round.round(3.5, 5));
        System.out.println("12 round to 6: " + Round.round(12, 6));
        System.out.println("11 round to 7: "+ Round.round(11, 7));
        System.out.println("5 round to 2: " + Round.round(5, 2));
        System.out.println("6.2 round to 2: " + Round.round(6.2, 2));
    }

    public static double round(double num, int multipleOf) {
        return Math.floor((num +  (double)multipleOf / 2) / multipleOf) * multipleOf;
    }
}
```

And here's the output

```
3.5 round to 5: 5.0
12 round to 6: 12.0
11 round to 7: 14.0
5 round to 2: 6.0
6.2 round to 2: 6.0
```

Comment: **multipleOf** is an int, so dividing it by 2 can cause problems.

Comment: if **multipleOf == 5** then **multipleOf/2 == 2**

Comment: @AmirPashazadeh: That's correct, I also needed to use floor, instead of round since I'm already adding `multipleOf/2`. See any other problems?

Answer (score 10):

```
int roundUp(int num) {
    return (int) (Math.ceil(num / 5d) * 5);
}
```

Comment: Tested this with my examples and it works. Even for any kind of multiples `public static int roundUp(double num, int multipleOf) {
        return  (int) (Math.ceil(num / (double)multipleOf) * multipleOf); }`

Answer (score 8):

```
int round(int num) {
    int temp = num%5;
    if (temp<3)
         return num-temp;
    else
         return num+5-temp;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
int roundUp(int num) {
    return ((num / 5) + (num % 5 > 0 ? 1 : 0)) * 5;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int getNextMultiple(int num , int multipleOf) {
    int nextDiff = multipleOf - (num % multipleOf);
    int total = num + nextDiff;
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 int roundToNearestMultiple(int num, int multipleOf){
        int floorNearest = ((int) Math.floor(num * 1.0/multipleOf)) * multipleOf;
        int ceilNearest = ((int) Math.ceil(num  * 1.0/multipleOf)) * multipleOf;
        int floorNearestDiff = Math.abs(floorNearest - num);
        int ceilNearestDiff = Math.abs(ceilNearest - num);
        if(floorNearestDiff <= ceilNearestDiff) {
            return floorNearest;
        } else {
            return ceilNearest;
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This Kotlin function rounds a given value 'x' to the closest multiple of 'n'

```
fun roundXN(x: Long, n: Long): Long {
    require(n > 0) { "n(${n}) is not greater than 0."}

    return if (x >= 0)
        ((x + (n / 2.0)) / n).toLong() * n
    else
        ((x - (n / 2.0)) / n).toLong() * n
}

fun main() {
    println(roundXN(121,4))
}
```

Output:  120

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin with extension function.

Possible run on [play.kotlinlang.org](https://pl.kotl.in/j_quDeGj3)

```kotlin
import kotlin.math.roundToLong

fun Float.roundTo(roundToNearest: Float): Float = (this / roundToNearest).roundToLong() * roundToNearest

fun main() {    
    println(1.02F.roundTo(1F)) // 1.0
    println(1.9F.roundTo(1F)) // 2.0
    println(1.5F.roundTo(1F)) // 2.0

    println(1.02F.roundTo(0.5F)) // 1.0
    println(1.19F.roundTo(0.5F)) // 1.0
    println(1.6F.roundTo(0.5F)) // 1.5
    
    println(1.02F.roundTo(0.1F)) // 1.0
    println(1.19F.roundTo(0.1F)) // 1.2
    println(1.51F.roundTo(0.1F)) // 1.5
}
```

Possible to use floor/ceil like this:
`fun Float.floorTo(roundToNearest: Float): Float = floor(this / roundToNearest) * roundToNearest`

Answer (score 1):

Some people are saying something like

```
int n = [some number]
int rounded = (n + 5) / 5 * 5;
```

This will round, say, 5 to 10, as well as 6, 7, 8, and 9 (all to 10).  You don't want 5 to round to 10 though.  When dealing with just integers, you want to instead add 4 to n instead of 5.  So take that code and replace the 5 with a 4:

```
int n = [some number]
int rounded = (n + 4) / 5 * 5;
```

Of course, when dealing with doubles, just put something like 4.99999, or if you want to account for all cases (if you might be dealing with even more precise doubles), add a condition statement:

```
int n = [some number]
int rounded = n % 5 == 0 ? n : (n + 4) / 5 * 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Method or logic to rounding up a number to nearest multiple of 5

```
double num = 18.0;
    if (num % 5 == 0)
        System.out.println("No need to roundoff");
    else if (num % 5 < 2.5)
        num = num - num % 5;
    else
        num = num + (5 - num % 5);
    System.out.println("Rounding up to nearest 5------" + num);
```

output :

```
Rounding up to nearest 5------20.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created a method that can convert a number to the nearest that will be passed in, maybe it will help to someone, because i saw a lot of ways here and it did not worked for me but this one did:

```
/**
 * The method is rounding a number per the number and the nearest that will be passed in.
 * If the nearest is 5 - (63->65) | 10 - (124->120).
 * @param num - The number to round
 * @param nearest - The nearest number to round to (If the nearest is 5 -> (0 - 2.49 will round down) || (2.5-4.99 will round up))
 * @return Double - The rounded number
 */
private Double round (double num, int nearest) {
    if (num % nearest >= nearest / 2) {
        num = num + ((num % nearest - nearest) * -1);
    } else if (num % nearest < nearest / 2) {
        num = num - (num % nearest);
    }
    return num;
}
```

Comment: Does not work for  31.428 => 31 , but does 32 when nearest =1

Answer (score 1):

In case you only need to round **whole numbers** you can use this function:

```
public static long roundTo(long value, long roundTo) {
    if (roundTo <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Parameter 'roundTo' must be larger than 0");
    }
    long remainder = value % roundTo;
    if (Math.abs(remainder) < (roundTo / 2d)) {
        return value - remainder;
    } else {
        if (value > 0) {
            return value + (roundTo - Math.abs(remainder));
        } else {
            return value - (roundTo - Math.abs(remainder));
        }
    }
}
```

The advantage is that it uses integer arithmetics and works even for large long numbers where the floating point division will cause you problems.

Answer (score 1):

```
int roundUp(int n, int multipleOf)
{
  int a = (n / multipleOf) * multipleOf;
  int b = a + multipleOf;
  return (n - a > b - n)? b : a;
}
```

source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/round-the-given-number-to-nearest-multiple-of-10/

Answer (score 1):

Praveen Kumars question elsewhere in this Thread

> "Why are we adding 4 to the number?"

is very relevant. And it is why I prefer to code it like this:

```
int roundUpToMultipleOf5(final int n) {
    return (n + 5 - 1) / 5 * 5;
}
```

or, passing the value as an argument:

```
int roundUpToMultiple(final int n, final int multipleOf) {
    return (n + multipleOf - 1) / multipleOf * multipleOf;
}
```

By adding 1 less than the multiple you're looking for, you've added *just enough* to make sure that a value of `n` which is an exact multiple will *not* round up, and any value of `n` which is *not* an exact multiple *will* be rounded up to the next multiple.

Answer (score 0):

Recursive:

```
public static int round(int n){
    return (n%5==0) ? n : round(++n);
}
```

Comment: the formula is (x+y-1)/y, dunno if recursive is just to look cool, imagine it was few thousands - bam StackOverflow.

Comment: you caught me. I often float around stack overflow trying to look cool. It was an alternative suggestion. There are numerous approaches.

Comment: @TimmyO'Mahony recursion is unnecessary and completely inefficient in this

Answer (score 0):

Just pass your number to this function as a double, it will return you rounding the decimal value up to the nearest value of 5;

if 4.25, Output 4.25

if 4.20, Output 4.20

if 4.24, Output 4.20

if 4.26, Output 4.30

if you want to round upto 2 decimal places,then use

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.##");
roundToMultipleOfFive(Double.valueOf(df.format(number)));
```

if up to 3 places, new DecimalFormat("#.###")

if up to n places, new DecimalFormat("#.**nTimes #**")

```
 public double roundToMultipleOfFive(double x)
            {

                x=input.nextDouble();
                String str=String.valueOf(x);
                int pos=0;
                for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
                {
                    if(str.charAt(i)=='.')
                    {
                        pos=i;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                int after=Integer.parseInt(str.substring(pos+1,str.length()));
                int Q=after/5;
                int R =after%5;

                if((Q%2)==0)
                {
                    after=after-R;
                }
                else
                {
                    after=after+(5-R);
                }

                       return Double.parseDouble(str.substring(0,pos+1).concat(String.valueOf(after))));

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use for rounding to multiples of a number:

```
private int roundToMultipleOf(int current, int multipleOf, Direction direction){
    if (current % multipleOf == 0){
        return ((current / multipleOf) + (direction == Direction.UP ? 1 : -1)) * multipleOf;
    }
    return (direction == Direction.UP ? (int) Math.ceil((double) current / multipleOf) : (direction == Direction.DOWN ? (int) Math.floor((double) current / multipleOf) : current)) * multipleOf;
}
```

The variable `current` is the number you're rounding, `multipleOf` is whatever you're wanting a multiple of (i.e. round to nearest 20, nearest 10, etc), and `direction` is an enum I made to either round up or down.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Round a given number to the nearest multiple of 5.

```
public static int round(int n)
  while (n % 5 != 0) n++;
  return n; 
}
```

Comment: this is one of the worst way because it needs to do a slow division multiple times

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method `Math.round(38/5) * 5` to get multiple of 5

It can be replace with `Math.ceil` or `Math.floor` based on how you want to round off the number

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to get nearest multiple of 5.

```
private int giveNearestMul5(int givenValue){
    int roundedNum = 0;
    int prevMul5, nextMul5;
    prevMul5 = givenValue - givenValue%5;
    nextMul5 = prevMul5 + 5;
    if ((givenValue%5!=0)){
        if ( (givenValue-prevMul5) < (nextMul5-givenValue) ){
            roundedNum = prevMul5;
        } else {
            roundedNum = nextMul5;
        }
    } else{
        roundedNum = givenValue;
    }

    return roundedNum;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if (n % 5 == 1){
   n -= 1;
} else if (n % 5 == 2) {
   n -= 2;
} else if (n % 5 == 3) {
   n += 2;
} else if (n % 5 == 4) {
   n += 1;
}
```

Comment: YandereDev, is that you?

Answer (score -4):

**CODE:**

```
    public class MyMath
    {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            runTests();
        }
        public static double myFloor(double num, double multipleOf) {
            return ( Math.floor(num / multipleOf) * multipleOf );
        }
        public static double myCeil (double num, double multipleOf) {
            return ( Math.ceil (num / multipleOf) * multipleOf );
        }

        private static void runTests() {
            System.out.println("myFloor (57.3,  0.1) : " + myFloor(57.3, 0.1));
            System.out.println("myCeil  (57.3,  0.1) : " + myCeil (57.3, 0.1));
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("myFloor (57.3,  1.0) : " + myFloor(57.3, 1.0));
            System.out.println("myCeil  (57.3,  1.0) : " + myCeil (57.3, 1.0));
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("myFloor (57.3,  5.0) : " + myFloor(57.3, 5.0));
            System.out.println("myCeil  (57.3,  5.0) : " + myCeil (57.3, 5.0));
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("myFloor (57.3, 10.0) : " + myFloor(57.3,10.0));
            System.out.println("myCeil  (57.3, 10.0) : " + myCeil (57.3,10.0));
        }
    }
```

**OUTPUT:**There is a bug in the myCeil for multiples of 0.1 too ... no idea why.

```
    myFloor (57.3,  0.1) : 57.2
    myCeil  (57.3,  0.1) : 57.300000000000004

    myFloor (57.3,  1.0) : 57.0
    myCeil  (57.3,  1.0) : 58.0

    myFloor (57.3,  5.0) : 55.0
    myCeil  (57.3,  5.0) : 60.0

    myFloor (57.3, 10.0) : 50.0
    myCeil  (57.3, 10.0) : 60.0
```