# Rounding numbers to specific multiples

Tags: java, function, math, rounding

How can I round to a specific multiple in Java?
In excel there is the `mround` function which allows for easy rounding to a specified multiple like so:

```
    mRound(variable,multiple)
```

so `mRound(x,3)` would return `9` if `x = 7.9` and `6` if `x = 7.2`.

All of the rounding functions I have found so far always round to the nearest whole number or to a specified number of decimal places but I want to be able to change the multiple for each variable. Does anyone know what function would be best for this situation?

Comment: No single function for that. `mul*round(x/mul)`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just divide by the number, round, and multiply by the number.

```
double mRound(double value, double factor) {
    return Math.round(value / factor) * factor;
}
```

Comment: Yes... although I suspect both `factor` and the return value should be `int`s.

Comment: @X-Zero: Making `factor` a `double` makes it possible to use values like `0.001` to round to the nearest thousandth.

Comment: How can we do the same with BigDecimal instead of double?