# How to increase a float to the next multiple of 0.5

Tags: java, floating-point

I would like to increase my `float` value to the first multiple of 0.5 after it.

For example, if I have: `float x = 3.397;` I would like it to become: `x = 3.5;`. Or, if I have: `float x = 7.895;` it should become `x = 8.0;`.

Comment: Yes, your requirement is clear. What is not clear is what problems you have or what question you want to ask.

Comment: Multiply by 2, round up, divide by 2

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I do not know how to do what I would like to be done

Comment: Perhaps `ceil(d * 2)/2`?

Comment: What should be the result of 0.5? of  large values in the range where xxxx.5 is not representable?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica That worked! Thank you!

Comment: lots of duplicates: [round BigDecimal to nearest 5 cents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2106615/995714), [How can I round up to the nearest multiple of the specified number?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38116385/995714), [Rounding up a number to nearest multiple of 5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9303604/995714), [Rounding numbers to specific multiples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10456564/995714)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple, but in every detail errors are hidden.

```
float nextHalf(float x) {
    // CORRECTED THIS: long n = Math.round(x * 2.0) + 1;
    return (float) (Math.ceil(x * 2.0) / 2);
}
```

With corrections due to @chux-ReinstateMonica.

As rounding methods round/floor/ceil target integer units of 1, for 0.5 one must first scale the numbers by a factor 2 and afterwards divide by 2.

Of course because of the incorporated exponent in a floating point number at some large numbers the difference between successive numbers is no longer below 1.0 so then

```
nextHalf(x) == nextHalf(x + 1.0)
```

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica my fault half heartedly reading the question. Corrected as no other answer

Comment: With `ceil()`, which returns `double`, `long n` is unnecessarily restrictive. Perhaps `double n` and avoid the "float might overflow long" problem?