# Round up current time to nearest 15 minutes using PHP

Tags: php, time

Is there a simple way of getting the current time and rounding it up to the next quarter of an hour?

For example if it is 12:36 then display 12:45
if it's 13:01 then display 13:15

etc

Comment: Should be able to do a variant of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303604/rounding-up-a-number-to-nearest-multiple-of-5

Comment: first hit on google -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480637/round-minute-down-to-nearest-quarter-hour

Comment: Rounding down and rounding up are slightly different, so this question is unique.  Links above go to a question for rounding down.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

here is your answer

```
$current_date = date('d-M-Y g:i:s A');
echo $current_date."<br/>";
$current_time = strtotime($current_date);

$frac = 900;
$r = $current_time % $frac;

$new_time = $current_time + ($frac-$r);
$new_date = date('d-M-Y g:i:s A', $new_time);

echo $new_date."<br/>";
```

**[LIVE DEMO](http://codepad.org/KVnnYKe8)**