# Display the smallest number from an input in Java

Tags: java

For example:

If the input is 550 the answer is 0
If the input is 32847923846 the answer is 2

The length of the input is variable.

I have tried arraylist and buffered reader class but i am not being able to get because the input's length is variable

Comment: if the length is variable... why not make the length of your array variable? Or use a `List`?

Comment: i used it but still there is error if you can help? how to use list ?

Comment: What is the error? Did you even bother looking up `List`? The official Java Documentation is a great source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step one, round the number down to the nearest 10, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303604/rounding-up-a-number-to-nearest-multiple-of-5).

```
int round(double i, int v){
    return Math.floor(i/v) * v;
}
```

And then minus this number from the original.

```
int value = 34554674;
int roundedDown = round(value, 10);

int smallest = value - roundedDown;
```

As seen by [this Ideone](http://ideone.com/Uryvfj).

Comment: If I understand OP correctly he looks for the smallest digit. Take a look at his `32847923846` example, the expected output is `2` and not `6`. The expected output for `123` would be `1`. But he accepted this answer, so whatever.

Comment: Ah yeah.. I must have misread, but yeah you're correct. Either he/she will comment and ask for a correction or this is one of those times where two wrongs made a right.

Comment: Or he/she will submit a wrong solution for his/her homework. I would be fine with that.

Comment: I feel like some sort of evil genius.

Comment: or evil idiot since it turns out I can't even read properly.

Answer (score 1):

Simple...
Change your `int i =1234;` value to `char[]` using this...

```
char[] chars = ("" + i).toCharArray();
```

after this use a loop to find the min value and print that...

Comment: How to find the min value ? Just like integer .

Comment: yes its the same way

Answer (score 0):

If input is only 1 line:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
char[] c = in.readLine().toCharArray();
char result = c[0];
for (char i : c) result = Math.min(result, i);
```

or if you have long integer:

```
long l;
// ...
char[] c = String.valueOf(l).toCharArray();
char result = c[0];
for (char i : c) result = Math.min(result, i);
```