# How do I round to the nearest ten?

Tags: java, rounding

How can I round a number to the nearest ten with no if statements? For example, 98 to 100.

```
int num = 87;
double t;
double d = 1.0 * num; // d = 87.0
t = d/100;
System.out.println(t);
```

Comment: Duplicate/similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303604/rounding-up-a-number-to-nearest-multiple-of-5

Answer (score 42):

You can use `Math.round(num/10.0) * 10`.

Comment: if you divide by 10d or 10.0, num can be any (primitive) number.

Comment: True, edited. @Peter

Answer (score 23):

```
answer = ((num+5)/10)*10; // if num is int
```

where `num` is `int` and to have more idea, read this quesiton.  [How to round a number to n decimal places in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java).
Edit:
if `num` is `double` add typecasting to expression `(long)((num+5)/10)` as suggested by @PeterLawrey

Comment: Are you sure? If `num` is 14.0 then this will evaluate to 20.

Comment: I might be having a senior moment but the last time I checked, (14.0 + 5) / 10 is 1.9 which becomes 2.0 on rounding. Remember that `Math.round` implements German rounding.

Comment: The cast of an int to an int is redundant, worse if it's already a long.

Comment: @sinsuren the cast is needed if it's a double but then you would use long if possible. It's an int for the OP's question.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I have changed according to your suggestion. Thankyou for improving answer quality.

Comment: Thanks @sinsuren it worked. Also thanks everyone who helped