# How to round to the next closest 30-Series

Tags: java, math, rounding

I need the easiest and shortes way, to round an integer to the next "30-series".

For example:

```
431 --> 450
459 --> 480
298 --> 300
```

Comment: @Reimeus what code should I write, if I have no idea how to do it?

Comment: For 450 as input, do you need, 450 or 500 as output?

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle 450

Comment: Even if you don't know how to do it, you should include what you have so far, since this feels like a homework question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: @nevets1219 it's not an homework question. I don't have anything concrete so far, else I'd have included it in my question.

Comment: Well a simple search yields multiple results: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9303604/rounding-up-a-number-to-nearest-multiple-of-5

Comment: Thanks @nevets1219

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the language you are using. A simple example could be

```
def round2multipleOfThirty(x):
 if x % 30 < 15:
         return x - x % 30
 else:
         return x + 30 - x % 30
```

which works in python. But do you actually want a round function? Your example numbers are always rounded up to the next greater multiple of 30. My function provided is a round which would provide

```
431 --> 420
459 --> 450
298 --> 300
```

Comment: I wrote "Java" in the tags.

Comment: Python REPL was just at hand ;) But it should be easily translatable into Java the same way and there is another answer dealing with the exact question in Java.

Comment: Easier : `(x + 29) / 30 * 30`

Comment: Yes, but be aware that for instance python 3 automatically converts divisions to float. But this is not default in other languages and therefore in general an easier and better answer.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle: Even easier: `x + (-x) % 30` (which works for floats like `x=0.5`, too).

Comment: @domna: Your solution won't translate well to a language like Java or C++, because for negative `x`, `x % 30 < 15` will always be true in those languages.