# Parallel prime factorization using an array of primes up to target

Tags: java

I’ve seen this question already being  asked on Stack but I couldn’t find any concrete answer or at least the answer I understand.
So here is my question:

How could I parallelize the factorization of a big number?

I’ve seen answers like this:
“ … He just needs to spawn a new thread for each factor found, then have some sort of synchronized object to collect all the factors”

But I don’t quite understand how this could be done.
Could someone please explain it using an example?

Comment: If you mean computing different portions using threads, chances are that will probably show things down unless you have a huge number to factor since setting up threads and managing synchronization increases overhead.  And if you do have a huge number you may want to search for factorization algorithms which do more than just check for division by existing primes.

Comment: Yes, I tried searching online but couldn’t find anything. Could you please be more specific, have you heard of some specific algorithm?

Comment: This should keep you busy for a while.  [Integer Factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list of primes. You can do it like this (for real large numbers it can take a while). Use a map to hold a frequency count of prime factors and the number of times they occur.

- continue dividing target by current prime until it doesn't divide
- then use `BigInteger` to check the value to see if it is a prime (this greatly speeds up the process if the remaining value is huge and a prime).
- continue until all factors have been found or you run out of primes.

```
long candidate = 498977279919318060L;

Map<Long, Integer> factors = new TreeMap<>();
for (long p : primes) {
    while (candidate % p == 0) {
        factors.compute(p, (k,v) -> v == null ? 1 : v+1);
        candidate/=p;
    }
    if (BigInteger.valueOf(candidate).isProbablePrime(99)) {
        factors.put(candidate,1);
        candidate = 1;
        break;
    }
}
if (candidate != 1) {
    System.out.println("factorization incomplete - stopped at " + candidate);
}

factors.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
2=2
3=5
5=1
7=1
19=3
29=1
73=2
101=1
137=1
```

You can verify the result by first, raising each factor to its frequency and then computing the product of those results using reduce.

```
long val = factors.entrySet().stream()
        .mapToLong(e -> (long) Math
                .pow(e.getKey().doubleValue(), e.getValue()))
        .reduce(1L, (a, b) -> a * b);

System.out.println(val);
```

prints

```
498977279919318060
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this amazing answer! However, I need to find a way to parallelize the factorization. I do have a list of primes up to the number I need to factorize and I should use it. In the lectures, we were introduced to trial division and we should somehow make it work in parallel. I just can’t see how this could be done as each step is  dependent upon the result of the previous one.

Comment: You need to provide more information.  I have no idea how you were told to do this in parallel or what that means exactly (other than using threads).

Comment: Ok. I'll try to explain. I was given the sequential version of sieve of Eratosthenes that produce an array of primes up to number N. I then need to factorize 100 numbers less that N*N where N is 2mil, 20mil,...2bil using this array and I must parallelize each factorization. Sequential algorithm we were shown uses this approach: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-program-for-efficiently-print-all-prime-factors-of-a-given-number/     and We should somehow adapt it to run in parallel and achieve speedups >1 contra sequential factorization.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59074797/parallelizing-sieve-of-eratosthenes-in-java.  And search the web.  There are articles on this.