# Dividing two integers and rounding up the result, without using floating point

Tags: c++

I need to divide two numbers and round it up. Are there any better way to do this?

```
int myValue = (int) ceil( (float)myIntNumber / myOtherInt );
```

I find an overkill to have to cast two different time. (the extern int cast is just to shut down the warning)

Note I have to cast internally to float otherwise

```
int a = ceil(256/11); //> Should be 24, but it is 23
              ^example
```

Comment: I doubt anybody is going to present a solution that is less ugly. What you have is the most legible way to do this. Wait, you aren't actually using literals in your real code are you? If you are, then just make them floating point literals. Otherwise, casting is the way to go.

Comment: You should use `double` instead of `float`, unless you're sure that you'll never have numbers larger than 16777216.

Comment: @yes123 don't wanna bother you but what do you mean by elegant, yours is very easy to read but the ones I posted may be more mathy and possibly faster

Comment: Duplicate of [C - Rounding integer division up (instead of truncating)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422712/c-rounding-integer-division-up-instead-of-truncating). The standard answer is [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2422722/902497).

Comment: @Raymond Chen Both this question and the one you mentioned, the OPs checked an answer than works for `unsigned` only or uses floating point.  Your reference also work only for `unsigned`.  As non-floating point solutions exists that work for all `int`, further Q & A in warranted.

Comment: I'm not sure the float solution works for all ints.  If your int and float are both 32 bits wide, then a float cannot exactly represent all possible ints, and the imprecision in representing one of those may bias the rounding (or maybe you get lucky).

Comment: @chux: Why would adding `(d-1)` not work with signed integers? It's arguably rounding towards zero for negative numbers, but that is the same direction as towards +inf in that case, thus "up".

Comment: @Damon I was caught on this yesterday too.  Example: For n = -7, d = 5, we would like -7/5 = -1.2 round up to -1.  But (-7+5-1)/5 = -3/5 which results in 0.  As to the "why". For positive numbers, adding the `d-1` compensates the normal division rounding down toward 0.  But when `n` is negative (d positive), the normal division rounds up (towards 0) without the compensation and gives the wrong answer with compensation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With help from DyP, came up with the following branchless formula:

```
int idiv_ceil ( int numerator, int denominator )
{
    return numerator / denominator
             + (((numerator < 0) ^ (denominator > 0)) && (numerator%denominator));
}
```

It avoids floating-point conversions and passes a basic suite of unit tests, as shown here:

- http://ideone.com/3OrviU

---

Here's another version that avoids the modulo operator.

```
int idiv_ceil ( int numerator, int denominator )
{
    int truncated = numerator / denominator;
    return truncated + (((numerator < 0) ^ (denominator > 0)) &&
                                             (numerator - truncated*denominator));
}
```

- http://ideone.com/Z41G5q

The first one will be faster on processors where IDIV returns both quotient and remainder (and the compiler is smart enough to use that).

Comment: You can leave out 8 parentheses, though you'll get a warning.

Comment: @DyP: Yes, the "branchless" characteristic is more important for compilers dumber than g++... which also corresponds to tiny processors where you really care about the performance.

Comment: finally understand it, c++ rounds down on positives and up on negatives, you could have just said that

Comment: @aaronman It discards the fractional part of an integer division, but that's equivalent.

Comment: We should downvote the accepted answer since it is incorrect, I deleted mine

Comment: @aaronman The accepted answer is **not** incorrect. Read the assumptions.

Comment: @aaronman: Because this site penalizes people who don't "accept" an answer.  So they end up choosing the one that's least bad.

Comment: I was thinking you could ensure the usage of the `idiv` instruction by using the `div` C++ function, but it looks like my version of g++ wont inline that even at `-O3`. (And does use `idivl` instruction in both of the listed versions...)

Comment: Didn't imagine my question would generate this buzz. Thanks everyone for parteciping. Also about performance do you think it's better jwodder solution?

Comment: Are you sure it's branchless?  I would expect the `&&` operator to introduce a branch because it requires short-circuit evaluation.

Comment: Perhaps you meant `... & ((numerator % denominator) != 0) ...`, which has the same effect but is more likely to produce branchless code?

Comment: @Adrian: I imagine most compilers will detect there are no side-effects there, and thus no short-circuiting needed.

Comment: "IDIV returns both quotient and remainder" <- Which processors are like that?

Answer (score 29):

Assuming that both `myIntNumber` and `myOtherInt` are positive, you could do:

```
int myValue = (myIntNumber + myOtherInt - 1) / myOtherInt;
```

Comment: If you suspect others have a hard time reading it, append a well written comment.

Comment: What about: `myIntNumber<0? myIntNumber/myOtherInt : (myIntNumber + myOtherInt - 1) / myOtherInt`?

Comment: Well I believe I will stick with the my ugiler (but maybe more readable) code

Comment: Other devs should learn to read this expresion if they find it confusing - it's not an uncommon idiom.

Comment: @yes123 Just make it a self-explanatory function. `int myValue = divide_and_round_up(myIntNumber, myOtherInt);` (or `div_ceil`)

Comment: @celtschk: I don't think that correctly handles negative divisor.

Comment: It does work given the stated assumption that both inputs are positive.

Comment: @Adrian: I was responding to celtschk's formula (as you can see if you click through to the linked code).  The wording unfortunately isn't clear, but it was too late to edit when I realized that.

Comment: Shoud not it be "int myValue = (myIntNumber + myOtherInt / 2) / myOtherInt;" ?

Comment: @xXx_CodeMonkey_xXx: No, this would be rounding to nearest (and also doesn't work wrt overflows).

Comment: `int myValue = (myIntNumber - 1) / myOtherInt + 1;` avoids overflow in case myOtherInt is large.

Comment: This expression is equivalent to @MrMartin's expression with the qualifier that both dividend and divisor are greater than 0.

Answer (score 5):

## Benchmarks

Since a lot of different methods are shown in the answers and none of the answers actually prove any advantages in terms of performance I tried to benchmark them myself. My plan was to write an answer that contains a *short* table and a definite answer which method is the fastest.

Unfortunately it wasn't that simple. (It never is.) It seems that the performance of the rounding formulas depend on the used data type, compiler **and** optimization level.

In one case there is an increase of speed by 7.5× from one method to another. So the impact can be significant for some people.

### TL;DR

For `long` integers the naive version using a type cast to `float` and `std::ceil` was actually the fastest. This was interesting for me personally since I intended to use it with `size_t` which is *usually* defined as `unsigned long`.

For ordinary `int`s it depends on your optimization level. For lower levels @Jwodder's solution performs best. For the highest levels `std::ceil` was the optimal one. With one exception: For the clang/`unsigned int` combination @Jwodder's was still better.

The solutions from the accepted answer never really outperformed the other two. You should keep in mind however that @Jwodder's solution doesn't work with negatives.

Results are at the bottom.

## Implementations

To recap here are the four methods I benchmarked and compared:

### [@Jwodder's version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17005390/3139807) (Jwodder)

```
template<typename T>
inline T divCeilJwodder(const T& numerator, const T& denominator)
{
    return (numerator + denominator - 1) / denominator;
}
```

### [@Ben Voigt's version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17005764/3139807) using modulo (VoigtModulo)

```
template<typename T>
inline T divCeilVoigtModulo(const T& numerator, const T& denominator)
{
    return numerator / denominator + (((numerator < 0) ^ (denominator > 0))
        && (numerator%denominator));
}
```

### [@Ben Voigt's version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17005764/3139807) without using modulo (VoigtNoModulo)

```
inline T divCeilVoigtNoModulo(const T& numerator, const T& denominator)
{
    T truncated = numerator / denominator;
    return truncated + (((numerator < 0) ^ (denominator > 0))
        && (numerator - truncated*denominator));
}
```

### [OP's implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17005364/3139807) (TypeCast)

```
template<typename T>
inline T divCeilTypeCast(const T& numerator, const T& denominator)
{
    return (int)std::ceil((double)numerator / denominator);
}
```

## Methodology

In a single batch the division is performed 100 million times. Ten batches are calculated for each combination of Compiler/Optimization level, used data type and used implementation. The values shown below are the averages of all 10 batches in milliseconds. The errors that are given are [standard deviations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation).

The whole source code that was used can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/Scindix/9a5ff2ec107f5f300e08b72c97b841f6). Also you might find [this](https://gist.github.com/Scindix/ba5a404ee0affac825a8981db078b043) script useful which compiles and executes the source with different compiler flags.

The whole benchmark was performed on a i7-7700K. The used compiler versions were GCC 10.2.0 and clang 11.0.1.

## Results

Now without further ado here are the results:

| `DataType` Algorithm | GCC -O0 | -O1 | -O2 | -O3 | -Os | -Ofast | -Og | clang -O0 | -O1 | -O2 | -O3 | -Ofast | -Os | -Oz |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `unsigned` |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **Jwodder** | **264.1 ± 0.9** | **175.2 ± 0.9** | **153.5 ± 0.7** | **175.2 ± 0.5** | 153.3 ± 0.5 | 153.4 ± 0.8 | **175.5 ± 0.6** | **329.4 ± 1.3** | **220.0 ± 1.3** | **146.2 ± 0.6** | **146.2 ± 0.6** | **146.0 ± 0.5** | **153.2 ± 0.3** | **153.5 ± 0.6** |
| VoigtModulo | 528.5 ± 2.5 | 306.5 ± 1.0 | 175.8 ± 0.7 | **175.2 ± 0.5** | 175.6 ± 0.7 | 175.4 ± 0.6 | 352.0 ± 1.0 | 588.9 ± 6.4 | 408.7 ± 1.5 | 164.8 ± 1.0 | 164.0 ± 0.4 | 164.1 ± 0.4 | 175.2 ± 0.5 | 175.8 ± 0.9 |
| VoigtNoModulo | 375.3 ± 1.5 | **175.7 ± 1.3** | 192.5 ± 1.4 | 197.6 ± 1.9 | 200.6 ± 7.2 | 176.1 ± 1.5 | 197.9 ± 0.5 | 541.0 ± 1.8 | 263.1 ± 0.9 | 186.4 ± 0.6 | 186.4 ± 1.2 | 187.2 ± 1.1 | 197.2 ± 0.8 | 197.1 ± 0.7 |
| **TypeCast** | 348.5 ± 2.7 | 231.9 ± 3.9 | 234.4 ± 1.3 | 226.6 ± 1.0 | **137.5 ± 0.8** | **138.7 ± 1.7** | 243.8 ± 1.4 | 591.2 ± 2.4 | 591.3 ± 2.6 | 155.8 ± 1.9 | 155.9 ± 1.6 | 155.9 ± 2.4 | 214.6 ± 1.9 | 213.6 ± 1.1 |
| `unsigned long` |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Jwodder | 658.6 ± 2.5 | 546.3 ± 0.9 | 549.3 ± 1.8 | 549.1 ± 2.8 | 540.6 ± 3.4 | 548.8 ± 1.3 | 486.1 ± 1.1 | 638.1 ± 1.8 | 613.3 ± 2.1 | **190.0 ± 0.8** | 182.7 ± 0.5 | 182.4 ± 0.5 | 496.2 ± 1.3 | 554.1 ± 1.0 |
| VoigtModulo | 1,169.0 ± 2.9 | 1,015.9 ± 4.4 | 550.8 ± 2.0 | 504.0 ± 1.4 | 550.3 ± 1.2 | 550.5 ± 1.3 | 1,020.1 ± 2.9 | 1,259.0 ± 9.0 | 1,136.5 ± 4.2 | **187.0 ± 3.4** | 199.7 ± 6.1 | 197.6 ± 1.0 | 549.4 ± 1.7 | 506.8 ± 4.4 |
| VoigtNoModulo | 768.1 ± 1.7 | 559.1 ± 1.8 | 534.4 ± 1.6 | 533.7 ± 1.5 | 559.5 ± 1.7 | 534.3 ± 1.5 | 571.5 ± 1.3 | 879.5 ± 10.8 | 617.8 ± 2.1 | 223.4 ± 1.3 | 231.3 ± 1.3 | 231.4 ± 1.1 | 594.6 ± 1.9 | 572.2 ± 0.8 |
| **TypeCast** | **353.3 ± 2.5** | **267.5 ± 1.7** | **248.0 ± 1.6** | **243.8 ± 1.2** | **154.2 ± 0.8** | **154.1 ± 1.0** | **263.8 ± 1.8** | **365.5 ± 1.6** | **316.9 ± 1.8** | **189.7 ± 2.1** | **156.3 ± 1.8** | **157.0 ± 2.2** | **155.1 ± 0.9** | **176.5 ± 1.2** |
| `int` |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| **Jwodder** | **307.9 ± 1.3** | **175.4 ± 0.9** | **175.3 ± 0.5** | **175.4 ± 0.6** | 175.2 ± 0.5 | 175.1 ± 0.6 | **175.1 ± 0.5** | **307.4 ± 1.2** | **219.6 ± 0.6** | **146.0 ± 0.3** | 153.5 ± 0.5 | 153.6 ± 0.8 | **175.4 ± 0.7** | **175.2 ± 0.5** |
| VoigtModulo | 528.5 ± 1.9 | 351.9 ± 4.6 | **175.3 ± 0.6** | **175.2 ± 0.4** | 197.1 ± 0.6 | 175.2 ± 0.8 | 373.5 ± 1.1 | 598.7 ± 5.1 | 460.6 ± 1.3 | 175.4 ± 0.4 | 164.3 ± 0.9 | 164.0 ± 0.4 | **176.3 ± 1.6** | 460.0 ± 0.8 |
| VoigtNoModulo | 398.0 ± 2.5 | 241.0 ± 0.7 | 199.4 ± 5.1 | 219.2 ± 1.0 | 175.9 ± 1.2 | 197.7 ± 1.2 | 242.9 ± 3.0 | 543.5 ± 2.3 | 350.6 ± 1.0 | 186.6 ± 1.2 | 185.7 ± 0.3 | 186.3 ± 1.1 | 197.1 ± 0.6 | 373.3 ± 1.6 |
| **TypeCast** | 338.8 ± 4.9 | 228.1 ± 0.9 | 230.3 ± 0.8 | 229.5 ± 9.4 | **153.8 ± 0.4** | **138.3 ± 1.0** | 241.1 ± 1.1 | 590.0 ± 2.1 | 589.9 ± 0.8 | 155.2 ± 2.4 | **149.4 ± 1.6** | **148.4 ± 1.2** | 214.6 ± 2.2 | 211.7 ± 1.6 |
| `long` |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Jwodder | 758.1 ± 1.8 | 600.6 ± 0.9 | 601.5 ± 2.2 | 601.5 ± 2.8 | 581.2 ± 1.9 | 600.6 ± 1.8 | 586.3 ± 3.6 | 745.9 ± 3.6 | 685.8 ± 2.2 | 183.1 ± 1.0 | 182.5 ± 0.5 | 182.6 ± 0.6 | 553.2 ± 1.5 | 488.0 ± 0.8 |
| VoigtModulo | 1,360.8 ± 6.1 | 1,202.0 ± 2.1 | 600.0 ± 2.4 | 600.0 ± 3.0 | 607.0 ± 6.8 | 599.0 ± 1.6 | 1,187.2 ± 2.6 | 1,439.6 ± 6.7 | 1,346.5 ± 2.9 | 197.9 ± 0.7 | 208.2 ± 0.6 | 208.0 ± 0.4 | 548.9 ± 1.4 | 1,326.4 ± 3.0 |
| VoigtNoModulo | 844.5 ± 6.9 | 647.3 ± 1.3 | 628.9 ± 1.8 | 627.9 ± 1.6 | 629.1 ± 2.4 | 629.6 ± 4.4 | 668.2 ± 2.7 | 1,019.5 ± 3.2 | 715.1 ± 8.2 | 224.3 ± 4.8 | 219.0 ± 1.0 | 219.0 ± 0.6 | 561.7 ± 2.5 | 769.4 ± 9.3 |
| **TypeCast** | **366.1 ± 0.8** | **246.2 ± 1.1** | **245.3 ± 1.8** | **244.6 ± 1.1** | **154.6 ± 1.6** | **154.3 ± 0.5** | **257.4 ± 1.5** | **591.8 ± 4.1** | **590.4 ± 1.3** | **154.5 ± 1.3** | **135.4 ± 8.3** | **132.9 ± 0.7** | **132.8 ± 1.2** | **177.4 ± 2.3** |

Now I can finally get on with my life :P

Comment: There's another complication of course -- "TypeCast" doesn't produce correct results when the input data is a 64-bit integer (`long` or `unsigned long`), because the cast to `double` loses precision.  OP's version of TypeCast using `float` produces incorrect results also for 32-bit integers (all cases tested here).

Comment: That too was my concern: the precision loss introduced by float/double representation will at some point cause the results to be incorrect, causing hard-to-track errors. It's more of an approximation, not a precise calculation for e.g. byte sizes.

Comment: Did you check the assembly code? GCC is widely known for performing all calculations for which the input data is known at compile time at compile time. I would generate a file with test data first, then load it in the test suite - just in case.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it is just easier to do a:

```
int result = dividend / divisor;
if(dividend % divisor != 0)
    result++;
```

Comment: And let the compiler optimize all that. That's just the best answer.

Comment: @Salamandar: Sorry: not the best. This is wrong for negative dividends.

Answer (score 1):

Integer division with round-up.

Only 1 division executed per call, no `%` or `*` or conversion to/from floating point, works for positive and negative `int`. See note (1).

```
n (numerator) = OPs myIntNumber;  
d (denominator) = OPs myOtherInt;
```

The following approach is simple.  `int` division rounds toward 0.  For negative quotients, this is a round up so nothing special is needed.  For positive quotients, add `d-1` to effect a round up, then perform an unsigned division.

Note (1) The usual divide by `0` blows things up and `MININT/-1` fails as expected on 2's compliment machines.

```
int IntDivRoundUp(int n, int d) {
  // If n and d are the same sign ... 
  if ((n < 0) == (d < 0)) {
    // If n (and d) are negative ...
    if (n < 0) {
      n = -n;
      d = -d;
    }
    // Unsigned division rounds down.  Adding d-1 to n effects a round up.
    return (((unsigned) n) + ((unsigned) d) - 1)/((unsigned) d);  
  }
  else {
    return n/d;
  }
}
```

---

[Edit: test code removed, see earlier rev as needed]

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
int ceil_of_division = ((dividend-1)/divisor)+1;
```

For example:

```
for (int i=0;i<20;i++)
    std::cout << i << "/8 = " << ((i-1)/8)+1 << std::endl;
```

Comment: Fails due to underflow.

Comment: example please?

Comment: When `dividend` is `std::limits<int>::min()` (assuming `dividend` is an `int`), you get [undefined behavior](If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined. [...]). And even if the behavior were wrap-around, you'd get the wrong sign.

Answer (score 0):

A small hack is to do:

```
int divideUp(int a, int b) {
    result = (a-1)/b + 1;
}
// Proof:
a = b*N + k (always)
if k == 0, then
  (a-1)       == b*N  - 1
  (a-1)/b     == N - 1
  (a-1)/b + 1 == N ---> Good !

if k > 0, then
  (a-1)       == b*N   + l
  (a-1)/b     == N
  (a-1)/b + 1 == N+1  ---> Good !
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using the ceil function before casting to int, you can add a constant which is very nearly (but not quite) equal to 1 - this way, nearly anything (except a value which is exactly or incredibly close to an actual integer) will be increased by one before it is truncated.

Example:

```
#define EPSILON (0.9999)

int myValue = (int)(((float)myIntNumber)/myOtherInt + EPSILON);
```

EDIT: after seeing your response to the other post, I want to clarify that this will round up, not away from zero - negative numbers will become less negative, and positive numbers will become more positive.