# Why do memory managers use (size + PAGE_SIZE-1) / PAGE_SIZE to calculate the number of pages to allocate?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, rounding, division, counting

I have met such a formula multiple times in various places (e.g.; Linux kernel and glibc). Why do they use this formula instead of simply:

```
pages = (size / PAGE_SIZE) + 1;
```

As a guess, I think the problem with the formula above is when the size is `PAGE_SIZE` aligned (a multiple of `PAGE_SIZE`) because, in such a case, it reports one more page than needed, thus we have to also do:

```
pages = (size / PAGE_SIZE) + 1;
if (!(size & (PAGE_SIZE-1))) /* is size a multiple of PAGE_SIZE? */
    pages--;
```

which is obviously more code than just `(size + PAGE_SIZE-1) / PAGE_SIZE`!

Comment: Your guess is correct

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: @EugeneSh. the question is as stated. I had a guess by just thinking about it but I wanted to confirm its correct and whether it is just that or there is some other thing about it. It can also help other lazy people.

Comment: @Dani perfect! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's used to get the ceiling of the division result, i.e. rounding the quotient up

The problem with

```
pages = (size / PAGE_SIZE) + 1;
if (!(size & (PAGE_SIZE-1))) /* is size a multiple of PAGE_SIZE? */
    pages--;
```

is not only a lot more code but also the fact that

- it has worse performance due to the branch
- it only works for powers of 2

Of course page size in a binary computer is always a power of 2, but `(size + PAGE_SIZE-1) / PAGE_SIZE` works for any value of the divisor

See also

- [Fast ceiling of an integer division in C / C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2745074/995714)
- [Rounding integer division (instead of truncating)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2422712/995714)
- [Dividing two integers and rounding up the result, without using floating point](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17005364/995714)
- [What's the right way to implement integer division-rounding-up?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41870852/995714)

Answer (score 3):

This is rounding up.  You add `(PAGE_SIZE - 1)` to `nbytes`  so in case you have an exact number of `PAGE_SIZE` `nbytes` then you get the minimum number of pages you need, and if you pass it by one, then you get a new page to give space for the extra byte.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to make it with the *log2* of the page size. In the Linux kernel source, it is **PAGE_SHIFT**. For example, if **PAGE_SIZE** is 4096 = 2^12 bytes, **PAGE_SHIFT** is 12 (i.e. log2(2^12)). So, to get the number of *pages* for a given *size*, the following formula is often used:

*pages* = (*size* + **PAGE_SIZE** - 1) >> **PAGE_SHIFT**

By the way, the page size is often defined as:

#define **PAGE_SIZE** (1 << **PAGE_SHIFT**)