# Converting 8-bit number to 8-bit binary in C recursively

Tags: c, recursion, binary, bit

How would I write a recursive solution in C that does this?
For example, if I input 9, it should output 00001001

Comment: sorry, typo has been fixed

Comment: Usually when I write code - I sit in front of the keyboard. Pick my nose and scratch my nuts. Have a bash. When I get stuck I post what I have written so far and ask for help

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/111928/2410359 http://stackoverflow.com/q/32208150/2410359 and many other SO posts

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void p(uint8_t n, int times){
    if(times){
        p(n >> 1, times-1);
        putchar("01"[n & 1]);
    }
}

void print_bin8(uint8_t num){
    p(num, 8);
}

int main(void){
    print_bin8(9);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A nice tight solution.

Comment: Thank you for your compliments.