# Divide by 3 and Round up (If need be) C#

Tags: c#, divide

I have come to a point in my game where I have to implement a feature which divides a number by 3 and makes it a whole integer. i.e. not 3.5 or 2.6 etc....

It was to be a whole number, like 3, or 5.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Math.Round(num / 3);
```

or

```
Math.Ceiling(num / 3);
```

or

```
Math.Truncate(num / 3);
```

Comment: This worked for me: gameManager.maxTries = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)gameManager.GameLevelImages[gameManager.GameLevel] / 3);    

Thank you

Comment: It's really important to know if `num` is an integer or not. If `num` is a floating-point type (or `decimal`), the above answer makes sense. If on the other hand `num` is an integer type, like `int`, the division will already truncate to return an integer result. To avoid that, write the denomiantor as `3.0` instead of just `3`. **Or** cast either the numerator or the denominator to `double` (like in the comment above).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen True, my assumption was that he/she was working with floating point numbers.

Answer (score 7):

Divide by three and round up can be done with the math functions:

```
int xyzzy = Math.Ceiling (plugh / 3);
```

or, if the input is an integer, with no functions at all:

```
int xyzzy = (plugh + 2) / 3;
```

This can also be done in a more generic way, "divide by `n`, rounding up":

```
int xyzzy = (plugh + n - 1) / n;
```

---

The `Ceiling` function is for explicitly rounding up (towards positive infinity). There are many other variations of rounding (floor, truncate, round to even, round away from zero and so on), which can be found [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14/difference-between-math-floor-and-math-truncate-in-net/580252#580252).

Comment: More generically, int xyzzy = (plugh + n - 1) / n;
The + n forces the round up, and the - 1 avoids it rounding up when it would have divided perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

Found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944/how-to-round-up-the-result-of-integer-division) which says that if you take the number to divide, add two, and divide by three you would get the correct answer. For example, 7/3 = 2.3, but (7+2)/3 = 3.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up! It is definitely worth to keep that in mind.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jacob. Really appreciate it!

Comment: This is a good way. But only when the number to divide is of an integer type. The division `/` is done differently for integer types, which makes this work.