# Next larger integer after dividing

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Round Up The Result Of Integer Division](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944/how-to-round-up-the-result-of-integer-division)

```
double d1=11, double d2=2
int i=d1/d2;
```

i would be 5.
But I would like it to return 6. (if the result is 5.01, I would want a 6 too)
How should I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
int i = (int)Math.Ceiling(d1/d2);
```