# Why is Math.ceil not rounding upwards?

Tags: java, math, ceil

I have the following code:

```
int total = 6;
int perPage = 5;
double pages = total/perPage;
double ceilPages = Math.ceil(pages);
out.println(ceilPages);
```

Which outputs `1.0`.

I thought it should output `2.0` because the result of `total/perPage` is `1.2`.

Why is it not rounding upwards to `2.0`?

Comment: You are performing an integer division not a floating point one.

Comment: `int ceilPages = (total + perPage - 1) / perPage;` is neater.

Comment: Did you try printing `pages` to see what value you passed into `Math.ceil()`?  That would have immediately told you the problem was not with `Math.ceil()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Round Up The Result Of Integer Division](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17944/how-to-round-up-the-result-of-integer-division)

Comment: (int)Math.ceil(3/2.0) will give answer 2

(int)Math.ceil(3/2) will give answer 1

In order to get the float value, you need to cast (or add .0) to one of the arguments

Answer (score 26, accepted):

you are casting an the result of integer division to a double.

You need to cast each part of the division to double BEFORE the result.

```
double pages = (double)total/(double)perPage;
```

The rest should work

Comment: Not each part. Casting the first one should be sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

`(int)Math.ceil(3/2.0)` will give answer 2

`(int)Math.ceil(3/2)` will give answer 1

In order to get the float value, you need to cast (or add .0) to one of the arguments

Answer (score 0):

double pages = Math.ceil((double)total/perPage);