# How to round up a double

Tags: java

I want to round up every double I get . I've searched and found Math.ceil but it is not working as I expected. For example :

```
Log.v("this", "" + Math.ceil(300 / 1000));-->returns 0 - expected 1 
Log.v("this",""+Math.ceil(100 / 1000));-->returns 0 - expected 1 
Log.v("this",""+Math.ceil(50 / 1000));-->returns 0 - expected 1 
Log.v("this",""+Math.ceil(700 / 1000));-->returns 0 - expected 1 
Log.v("this",""+Math.ceil(1000 / 1000)); -->this is ok
Log.v("this",""+Math.ceil(1020 / 1000));-->returns 1 - expected 2
```

What should I do ?

Comment: Math.ceil((double)300 / 1000)

Comment: `Double.parseDouble(Math.ceil(300/1000));`

Comment: my bad, ignore my answer, I mistook the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not rounding doubles, you are rounding integers!

When you do

```
700 / 1000
```

You are making an integer division (as both sides are integers!)

```
System.out.println(700/1000) == 0 //Well, you know what i mean.
```

You need to have a double, so you need to promote one of the two sides to a higher number (int -> double), so that the division is now for doubles:

```
700 / (double) 1000 == 0.7
```

Ceiling will then work properly.

Comment: Casting with `(double)` is one way to do it.  One can also simply add a decimal point or `d` suffix:  `700 / 1000.0` or `700 / 1000d` will also work.

Answer (score 0):

As you start with two integers and want to end up with an integer it is better to not do this via floating point math:

```
public static int integerDivideRoundUp(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    int q = numerator / denominator;
    int r = numerator % denominator;
    return r == 0 ? q : q + 1;
}
```

i.e. if there is no remainder in the divide, return the integer division result, otherwise return one more.

Here is a branchless verison based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5883806/360211):

```
public static int integerDivideRoundUp(int numerator, int denominator)
{
    int q = numerator / denominator;
    int r = numerator % denominator;
    return q - (-r >> (Integer.SIZE - 1));
}
```

Usage:

```
Log.v("this", "" + integerDivideRoundUp(300, 1000));
```